# How to repair "sudo: /etc/sudoers is mode 0640, should be 0440?"

Tags: sudo, chmod

Why might `sudo chmod -R a+w *` cause

```
sudo: /etc/sudoers is mode 0640, should be 0440 sudo:   
no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
```

and how might it be made to work?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/50704/sudo-error-is-mode-0777-should-be-0440?rq=1

Comment: possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/50704/sudo-error-is-mode-0777-should-be-0440?rq=1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think your best bet is to start the system in recovery mode (see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92556/how-do-i-boot-into-a-root-shell) for instructions), drop to root shell and do `chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers`.

EDIT: as Mik suggested below, the following should work as well without rebooting the system:

```
pkexec chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers
```

Comment: You could also try using `pkexec chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers` without going into recovery mode.

Comment: Thanks a million! BTW: also had to `pkexec chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/README`. I wonder if I broke anything else in /etc. Meh.

Comment: @Mik Thanks a lot. You have saved me so much time. I thought I'd have to re-install Ubuntu. Although can you tell me: Now that most of the system is 0777 permitted, is it dangerous to work on internet?

Comment: @Aayush Although we can't really discuss it here, see [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/20105/for-security-reasons-why-should-var-www-not-have-chmod-777) regarding 777 permissions and refer to other questions on the site for resetting the correct permissions on files and directories.

Answer (score 2):

**Why might the command cuase this to happen?** I suspect you ran the command while your current directory was `/etc`!

`sudo` refuses to work if the permissions of `/etc/sudoers` have been tamprered with to avoid compromising the system. You will have to fix the permissions using recovery mode unless you have another way of getting root access.