# sudo error: /etc/sudoers is mode 02460, should be 0440

Tags: 12.04, permissions, sudo

I am trying to change file permission but I was not able to access root from terminal. This is the error:

```
smartleaven05@smartleaven05-All-Series:~$ sudo
sudo: /etc/sudoers is mode 02460, should be 0440
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

Comment: Perhaps this Question and Answer might help: http://askubuntu.com/q/189818/57576

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sudo error, is mode 0777, should be 0440](http://askubuntu.com/questions/50704/sudo-error-is-mode-0777-should-be-0440)