# Resetting /home permission

Tags: permissions, home-directory

I changed the permission of `/home` folder to `777` and now I cannot access my account and login only as a guest (Ubuntu 14.04) with no sudo support.

Permission in home folder is as follows:

```
drwxr-xr-x 134 root root 12288 Dec 14 11:47 etc
d---------   4 root root  4096 Dec 14 09:50 home
drwxr-xr-x  24 root root  4096 Dec 11 23:04 lib
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Dec  4 18:05 lib32
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Dec  4 18:05 lib64
drwx------   2 root root 16384 Nov 30 23:42 lost+found
```

I will appreciate if there is a fix other than reinstall.

Comment: sorry, to clarify the permission of home directory shows up as : d---------   4 root root  4096 Dec 14 09:50 home

Comment: If PolicyKit is installed, try `pkexec chmod 755 /home`, I'm not sure, but let's see if it do the trick.

Comment: Try [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/50704/sudo-error-is-mode-0777-should-be-0440) it is about a different problem, but you can found how to enter into GRUB and get root privilege, so you could change /home permission with `chmod 755 /home`.

Answer (score 7):

You must boot into recovery mode:

a- Switch on your computer.

b- Quickly press and hold the Shift key, which will bring up the GNU GRUB menu.

c- Select the line which starts with ---- Advanced options.

d- Select the line ending with ----- recovery mode,something like:

```
Ubuntu GNU/Linux, with Linux 3.16.0-28-generic (recovery mode)
```

e-  Your PC should display a menu with a number of options.

f-  Select the line with ---- Drop to root shell prompt.

g-  You start in a terminal as root with the root partition mounted read-only.

Run it:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
mount --all
chmod 755 /home
chmod -Rf 700 /home/raj
chown -R raj /home/raj
reboot
```

Comment: Alternatively you can press `Ctrl+Alt+F3` and run the same commands (excluding the `mount` commands) as `sudo`. Thanks for this answer btw, helped me out after I totally stuffed my home dir permissions :P

Answer (score 0):

You want your /home permissions the same as /etc or /lib... I don't know the chmod numbers but these should do it:

```
sudo chmod a+rx /home
sudo chmod u+w /home
```

If you recursively changed all the folders in /home then you'll have some recursive (`-R`) chmod'ing to do, and is your user still the owner of his own home? If not, use `chown` (probably `sudo chown` unless you're root at the time) and change back to the the rightful owner.

Comment: I can only login as a guest which does not support sudo command!

Comment: now root own home and I as a guest I cannot see what is inside home!

Comment: `chmod` can't change the owner, that must've happened before. ProTip: You can change the owner with `chown`

Comment: that also requires sudo access which guest account does not allow.

Comment: since /home is now owned by root and I have setup root pw I cannot access /home. Is there a way to set root pw while loged on as a guest (with no sudo access)?

Comment: sorry, I have NOT setup root password!

Comment: hmmm, no sudo isn't good... a live cd/usb could log in and change any files (just like root would) and sudo should work while running from the live cd. But permanently fixing sudo may be troublesome later. OR there is some sort of "safe mode" or "single user mode" you might be able to boot into now and become root, but I'm not very familiar with that.

Comment: you could chroot into it from another installation or livecd enviroment

Comment: Good idea, can you please let me know full chroot command and do you know if needs root pw?

Comment: `chroot` wouldn't be needed just to change permissions & owners