# how to copy old user account to new user account?

Tags: users, administrator

My old user account is not working at all some corrupted files I guess.

The other 2 accounts are working normal.

So I create a new admin account and I wonder how can I copy all my settings, passwords, files from old admin account to new account.

I cant use old admin account gets frozen very badly so will help lots if I can do the migration from new admin account.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're basically asking: "How to copy settings and files from my user account to a new user account, skipping some settings?"

#### Migrating to a new user account

To move files from user `old` to `new`, you need to copy over the files and change the ownership accordingly:

```
sudo cp -r -d --preserve=mode,timestamps -T ~old ~new
sudo chown -R new: ~new
```

This should copy the files without modifying paths.

Now log in to a shell as `new`. Either switch to a VTY using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> and login as `new` or login from a terminal using `su new`. If you chose the first method, you can switch back with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>. From this point, it's assumed that you're logged in as `new`.

If symbolic links exist which point to their old directories, find those links:

```
find ~ -lname '*/old/*' -ls
```

The file names of the symbolic links are printed, but no action has been taken. To create a new symlink `~new/path/to/symlink` pointing to `~old/point/to/target`, overwriting the old one, run:

```
ln -sf ~old/point/to/target ~new/path/to/symlink
```

There could be configuration files referring to the old ones, you can find those files with `grep`:

```
grep -HrnI 'old' ~
```

If you get many results, consider being more specific, i.e. replace `old` by `/home/old`. Files will be listed with lines matching the search criteria, but no action is taken.

#### Debugging the old account

If you copy all settings and files, you're better off with removing the problematic files. For optimal results, it's a good idea to logout the subject user from a GUI session and log in a virtual console (switch to it using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>).

If you're suddenly being logged out, check `~/.xsession-errors`. You can do so by running:

```
less ~/.xsession-errors
```

Use arrow keys, Page Up/Down, Home or End to navigate, press <kbd>Q</kbd> to quit.

Sometimes the `.gconfd/saved_state` file gets corrupt. You can remove this file with:

```
rm .gconfd/saved_state
```

After doing this, switch back to a GUI login by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>. Log in and if the problem went away, you're done. Otherwise, log out and switch back to the virtual console using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>.

Another directory that can be emptied is `~/.cache`:

```
rm -r ~/.cache/*
```

Instead of loosing all files and settings, temporary move some folders. That can be done with:

```
mv folder{,-orig}
```

If a folder was not causing issues, remove the newly created folder and restore the old one:

```
rm -r folder
mv folder{-orig,}
```

Some folders that could cause problems (some may be nonexistent, in that case skip to the next folder):

```
.gnome
.gnome2
.kde
.config
.local
```

As with every modification, switch back to a GUI login and test it.

Comment: wow looks very very complicated for me... i dont get all the commands is there an easier way?...

Comment: Those are shell commands, just login in [a terminal](http://askubuntu.com/q/38162/6969) and execute those.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have already created your `newuser` and the home folder for the `newuser` exists:

**(1/2) Copy all the files to the new user:**

```
sudo rsync -ah --progress /home/olduser/. /home/newuser
```

Notes:

- `rsync` is a function similar but generally better than `cp`. It has more options etc
- `-a` command retains the permissions of the original files (we will sort ownerships in step 2)
- `-h` command turns output info into a human readable format (i.e. file sizes etc)
- `--progress` adds a progress bar for each file
- the `/.` on the end of the `olduser` location makes it include hidden files (this will make sure that your `bash_aliases` and `bashrc` files etc are copied across and not just normal files. This option is what migrates your settings.)

**(2/2) Change the owner of the copied files**

Now we change all the ownerships of the files:

```
sudo chown -R --from=olduser:oldusergroup newuser:newusergroup /home/newuser
```

Notes:

- `chown` is a function to CHange-OWNership of files
- `-R` makes it recursive. (If you are just changing one file you don't need this but we are changing all files and directories and everything within your new user folder and so recursive is needed)
- `--from=olduser:oldusergroup` this makes sure that we don't change any files (especially relevant for hidden files) that are 'owned' by root. Changing these could mess up a lot. This `--from` option tells `chown` that we only want to change files and folders that are currently owned by `olduser`.

This worked for me and, although I explained a lot here, actually it's only 2 main commands so the process is really simple once you work out how to keep the permissions etc.