# voice is echoing on headphone

Tags: indicator-sound, soundcard

I am using ubuntu 11.04 and whenever I am using headphone for music but the voice is echoing. But with simple system speaker it is good .Don't know why it is showing error like this.Please help me to solve this.Any help will be appreciable

Answer (score 3):

That echo could come from your microphone in your headset. You need to mute the microphone sound.

[Open a terminal](https://askubuntu.com/q/38162/6969) and run the `alsamixer` program. Use arrow left/right keys to move between sliders and press <kbd>M</kbd> for (un)muting a slider. Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> when done and run `exit` to close the terminal.

[image: Alsamixer window]