# Xsensors shows only one temperature

Tags: gnome, dell, sensors

I have been trying to find out the temperatures on my Laptop since I feel it has been overheating. the processor seems fine but the HDD is definitely on the fritz.

Problem is that the applet is only showing one temperature. I do not know how to increase the displays. Can anyone help out please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, install [lm-sensors](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lm-sensors) [image: Install lm-sensors]. which contains a program for detecting sensors on your machine. Next, [open a terminal](https://askubuntu.com/q/38162/6969) and run:

```
sudo sensors-detect
```

Follow the instructions (usually, pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> to accept the defaults is enough):

```
# sensors-detect revision 5861 (2010-09-21 17:21:05 +0200)
# System: CLEVO CO. B7130 (laptop)

This program will help you determine which kernel modules you need
to load to use lm_sensors most effectively. It is generally safe
and recommended to accept the default answers to all questions,
unless you know what you're doing.

Some south bridges, CPUs or memory controllers contain embedded sensors.
Do you want to scan for them? This is totally safe. (YES/no):
```

After a few questions, you've to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> once again to get a summary:

```
....
Next adapter: DPDDC-C (i2c-14)
Do you want to scan it? (YES/no/selectively): 

Now follows a summary of the probes I have just done.
Just press ENTER to continue:
```

On the last question if you'd like to add modules to `/etc/modules`, type `yes` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
Driver `coretemp':
  * Chip `Intel digital thermal sensor' (confidence: 9)

To load everything that is needed, add this to /etc/modules:
#----cut here----
# Chip drivers
coretemp
#----cut here----
If you have some drivers built into your kernel, the list above will
contain too many modules. Skip the appropriate ones!

Do you want to add these lines automatically to /etc/modules? (yes/NO)
```

After exiting `sensors-detect`, the modules are unloaded again and won't be loaded automatically until the next boot, so load the modules manually using `sudo modprobe module-name`. I had a module named `coretemp`, so I ran the next command to get extra sensors:

```
sudo modprobe coretemp
```

If you restart `xsensors`, the new sensor will become available. Another command from the `lm-sensors` package is `sensors` which shows its output in the terminal. Example output of `sensors`:

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:       +44.0°C  (crit = +105.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:      +41.0°C  (high = +95.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0001
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 2:      +39.0°C  (high = +95.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
```