# I got the error "resource is busy" while trying to mount my hard drive

Tags: partitioning, filesystem, mount, ntfs

While trying to mount my hard drive to copy all the necessary data from my broken drive to this one, I got an error saying:

```
# mount -t ntfs /dev/sda1 /mnt/dominik/
fuse: mount failed: Device or resource busy
```

This is my `fdisk -l` if that helps.

```
# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 640.1 GB, 640135028736 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 77825 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x70000000
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1       77826   625130496    7  HPFS/NTFS
```

And just to let you know I can see this partition in Computer but when I try to access it I get this error

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that `/dev/sda1` is already mounted under `/media/ACER`. Nautilus automatically mounts partitions when selecting it on the left side. You cannot mount a partition multiple times (leaving out `--bind` mounts).

Comment: Try doing mount -l to see what is already mounted

Comment: Acer is /dev/sdb1 - it's a different hard drive.

Comment: So what is the solution to this issue?? You did not tell!

Comment: @Mediterran81 The solution is using the old mount point OR unmounting the old one. If you open [a terminal](http://askubuntu.com/q/38162/6969) you can get a list of mounted filesystems by running `mount` without arguments.

Comment: Ok, thanks, that is logical. It just happened I did not understand why the system was unable to overwrite infos about the same mounting point. Actually, I uncommented the line corresponding to the External Drive that matters, in fstab file (using dynamic mounting instead of static one) and everything is back to normal! Thanks for the confirmation :)

Answer (score 1):

Solve for me :

`sudo apt-get purge  multipath-tools`

say yes

then

`sudo  reboot`

;)

Answer (score 0):

If you had the USB drive connected before you booted try disconnecting it and reconnecting to the booted system and it should auto mount.