# Unable to change brightness in a Lenovo laptop

Tags: laptop, kubuntu, intel-graphics, brightness, lenovo

Brightness adjustment keys <<kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>⇑</kbd>/<kbd>⇓</kbd>> have no effect (although they are recognized by the environment), and I can't change the brightness using GUI tools as well. This seems like a problem in Linux itself, not the desktop environment.

I can change the brightness in Windows OS, so it's not some kind of hardware fault.

Details:
          Lenovo B570 (Model Name: 20093)
          Integrated Intel HD graphics card
          Kubuntu 11.04 (Linux 2.6.38-10-generic, KDE 4.7.0), everything up to date
          No proprietary graphics drivers (only Wi-Fi one)

What I've tried:

- Edit `/etc/default/grub`↦`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`: `acpi_osi=Linux`, `acpi_backlight=vendor`, `nomodeset`. And yes, I did `update-grub`
- Edit `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` (no such file, even after `sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg`)
- Edit `/proc/acpi/video/VGA/LCD/brightness` (no such file)
- `sudo setpci -s 00:02.0 F4.B=XX` (no effect)
- `xbacklight -set XX` ("`No outputs have backlight property`")

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: This has been fixed in Ubuntu 11.10!

Comment: This appears broken again in Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: And Ubuntu 16.04 still.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change LCD brightness from command line (or via script)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/149054/how-to-change-lcd-brightness-from-command-line-or-via-script)

Comment: On my lenovo legion 5, I fixed it by changing the BIOS to Switchable graphics instead of Discrete graphics, that fixed brightness controls and also graphics recovering from suspend.

Comment: Same problem on Lenovo Thinkpad Yoga!

Comment: And Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a lenovo ideapad z400.

I tried all the TIPS listed above, no success.

So I found a different one that worked very well :

Put the following line in /etc/default/grub

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_backlight=vendor acpi_osi=Linux resume=/dev/sdYY"
```

YY = Swap area, use swapon -s to see you swap device.

Execute an update-grub as root

After the reboot the problem was solved.

Comment: It worked for me, however, something curious happened. When the brightness is set to the max, the screen shows no brightness (completely dark), any suggestion? Thanks

Answer (score 46):

If the GUI tools fail, try to use the [terminal](https://askubuntu.com/q/38162/6969) for it.

1. [Open a terminal](https://askubuntu.com/q/38162/6969)
2. Run: `ls /sys/class/backlight/*/brightness`. Example output would be:

   ```
   /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
   ```
3. If nothing is found, the kernel does not support brightness control (missing drivers?). Otherwise, you can use the below commands (replace `acpi_video0` accordingly):

   - Get the current brightness level:

     ```
     cat /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
     ```
   - Get the maximum brightness level:

     ```
     cat /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/max_brightness
     ```

   These commands return brightness levels which ranges from zero to *max_brightness* (see above).
4. To change the brightness level, you need to write a number to the `brightness` file. This cannot be done by an editor like `gedit`. Say you want to change your brightness to 5, you have to run:

   ```
   echo 5 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
   ```

   Alternatively, if you just want to set the brightness level to the highest available:

   ```
   sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness < /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/max_brightness
   ```

Comment: Sure there are some problems with drivers! If this command line stuff worked, GUI would work too. But of course it does not work – _

Comment: @Lekensteyn: [did not worked, 11.04 Ubuntu using] - I have tried a lot but it did not worked realtime. Did you mean when changing this it will show live or after reboot?

Comment: Changes are realtime.

Comment: Even as super user I could not change the brightness level using tee. Why might that be?

Comment: @Galen If you have not made a mistake in writing to the file, then it could be a model-specfic issue. Try reporting it as bug or search for your laptop model and "linux backlight".

Comment: Works in ubuntu 17 as well. Thanks

Comment: Added this as a quicklaunch button to the xfce panel on my T420  `sudo sh -c "echo brightness 0-$(cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/max_brightness) && echo $(read line && echo $line) > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness"`

Comment: Sucks to use the terminal for such things.

Answer (score 10):

Try [this](http://itsfoss.com/fix-brightness-ubuntu-1310/). It worked for my Ubuntu 14, Lenovo B570, Intel Graphics.

Open a terminal and create the following configuration file, if it does not exist:

**sudo touch /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf**

Now we need to edit this file. You can use any editor be it a terminal one or graphical.

**sudo gedit /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf**

Add the following lines to this file:

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier  "card0"
        Driver      "intel"
        Option      "Backlight"  "intel_backlight"
        BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"

EndSection
```

Save it. Log out and log in back.

Comment: Thank you - This also worked on a Samsung N220 Netbook w/ Integrated Intel Graphics (GMA 3150) running Xubuntu 15.04 "vivid"

Comment: Nope, that killed my X. had to remove the file in the recovery console again.

Comment: This does did not work on Lenovo P500.

Comment: This worked for me on a Thinkpad T460 with Ubuntu 17.04, I just had to log out and then log in.

Comment: To check the PCI bus ID run `lspci -nn`. That said, this didn't work for me in a Thinkpad E490.

Comment: I'm not sure this answer deserves the points it has gained - it is a copy/paste of an answer posted on an external forum without providing /why/ this when pasted into a configuration file -might work-; Enrico provides how to find maybe the bus ID though mine of is a different format 00:02.0 and I am assuming that conversion would be valid, but how do I know this is card0? It did not work for me and the answer doesn't provide any explanation which might help when debugging.

Comment: Does not work with Lenovo Thinkpad Yoga.

Answer (score 9):

1. Install `linux-kamal-mjgbacklight` - a patch for Linux kernel.

   - Check whether it will work for you:
     `lsmod | grep ^i915`
     Something like `i915 331519 3` should appear. **If there's no output, this will not work.**
   - `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kamalmostafa/linux-kamal-mjgbacklight`
   - Install updates (`sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade`)
2. Reboot.
3. Now you can use the terminal to adjust brightness, as **[suggested](https://askubuntu.com/q/57236#57610)** by [Lekensteyn](https://askubuntu.com/users/6969/lekensteyn).
   If it's OK for you to change brightness with terminal+`sudo`, this is the end of the answer.
   If you are on GNOME desktop, brightness may even function fully already.
4. Download my [brightness changer script](http://ideone.com/yPlo5), allow it to be executed, and put it to **/usr/local/bin/**:
   `wget -O brightness http://ideone.com/plain/yPlo5`
   `chmod +x brightness`
   `sudo mv brightness /usr/local/bin`
5. We have to allow the brightness file to be edited, so that `sudo` isn't needed everywhere.
   Also, we want to make the brightness setting restore itself to the previous setting when the system boots (it is not saved by default, unfortunately).

   The mentioned `brightness` script can handle it all (with `restore` parameter), just add it to autorun.
   To do this we will edit **/etc/rc.local** (`sudo nano /etc/rc.local` or any editor instead of nano).
   Add the following line before the `exit 0` line:
   `/usr/local/bin/brightness restore`
6. It is best to reboot now.
7. So the `brightness` script works. You may go to terminal any time and type these:

   - `brightness` - get current brightness setting
   - `brightness value` - set the brightness to **value**
   - `brightness inc step`, `brightness dec step` - increase or decrease the brightness by **step** (if it's not specified, a default value is used from the configuration file, usually 10% of maximal brightness)
8. Now you might want to map brightness change to your hotkeys.

   - Set *XF86BrightnessUp* to `brightness inc`
   - Set *XF86BrightnessDown* to `brightness dec`
9. If you want to tweak something, make sure to look at **/etc/bx_brightness.conf**
   You can change the step by which brightness is changed with `brightness inc`/`dec`

---

Thanks to [Toz](http://ubuntuforums.org/member.php?u=27546) for his priceless help in [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1827810).

Comment: This is no longer needed in Ubuntu 11.10

Answer (score 4):

I think I found an easy and least effect to the existed things' way for adjusting intel_backlight using udev rules.

I noticed "change" action of "backlight" subsystem when I press <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd> on my Lenovo G360 notebook running kernel 3.2. So I wrote a rules of `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-writeintelbacklight.rules` as below:

```
ACTION=="change", SUBSYSTEM=="backlight", RUN+="/usr/sbin/writeintelbacklight.sh"
```

Make the shell script `/usr/sbin/writeintelbacklight.sh` contain:

```
#!/bin/bash

intelmaxbrightness=`cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/max_brightness`
acpimaxbrightness=`cat /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/max_brightness`
scale=`expr $intelmaxbrightness / $acpimaxbrightness`
acpibrightness=`cat /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness`
newintelbrightness=`expr $acpibrightness \* $scale`
curintelbrightness=`cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/actual_brightness`
if [ "$newintelbrightness" -ne "$curintelbrightness" ]
then
  echo $newintelbrightness > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
fi
exit 0
```

Of course, you need do a `sudo chmod +x /usr/sbin/writeintelbacklight.sh`.

Comment: Added "acpi_backlight=vendor acpi_osi=linux video.brightness_switch_enabled=1" into grub boot kernel parameters, "Fn + Up/Down" to change brigtness works on my G360. It's no need to write a Udev rules like above.

Comment: It seems adding only one kernel parameter "acpi_backlight=vendor" also works on my G360 now. But, both methods of adding kernel parameters will stop work occasionly.

The detail of my case see:
Bug 44809 - [Arrandale backlight] Brightness via RANDR has no effect on Sony VAIO VPCYA1V9E: https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=44809

Answer (score 4):

*This will not get your Fn keys working, but you will be able to assign any other key to adjust brightness.*

I tried several of these solutions, but nothing worked for me until I found this little indicator program http://codevanrohde.nl/wordpress/?p=128. With it you can set up hot keys to control brightness, use your mousewheel or select from a drop down list in the indicator. I have replaced 'Fn' with 'Win+Alt' which is very similar for my hands and now I can also use it with an external keyboard!

To add PPA and install:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:indicator-brightness/ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install indicator-brightness
```

Hot keys should be assigned to:

```
/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/indicator-brightness/indicator-brightness-adjust --up
```

and

```
/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/indicator-brightness/indicator-brightness-adjust --down
```

*Footnote: Out of the box, the birghtness indicator recognizes 7 levels of brightness in my system. By adding `acpi_backlight=vendor` to the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub`, that number is bumped up to 16!*

Answer (score 2):

I have a Thinkpad T450s with Nvidia graphics and binary drivers on Ubuntu 14.04. In order to get the backlight working I had to edit the /etc/X11/xorg.conf file by adding the following line to the intel device definition (The xorg.conf-file is created when installing the binary drivers):

```
Option      "Backlight"  "intel_backlight"
```

The complete section is now:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "intel"
    Driver "intel"
    BusID "PCI:0@0:2:0"
    Option "Backlight" "intel_backlight"
    Option "AccelMethod" "SNA"
EndSection
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work for KDE users as it written in [https://launchpad.net/~kamalmostafa/+archive/linux-kamal-mjgbacklight](https://launchpad.net/%7Ekamalmostafa/+archive/linux-kamal-mjgbacklight)

> NOTES FOR KDE DESKTOP USERS
>
> KDE desktop users: This PPA may NOT fix your backlight control hotkeys: This fix requires a kernel module to supply the new `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight` interface (which will work regardless of your desktop) and also a desktop module to access that interface. For Gnome, the updated gnome-power-manager in this PPA supplies that, but the equivalent for KDE has not yet been developed."

However you can try a workaround found [here](http://old.nabble.com/-Bug-271467--New%3A-PowerDevil-cannot-control-screen-brightness-using-new--sys-class-backlight-intel_backlight-interface-p31454651.html).

That says to type in the terminal `echo XXX | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` where XXX is an integer value.

In my case XXX can be a value from 0 to 4882, but be careful: if you write 0 the screen will be completely black and you'll se nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a patch you can do.

Create this script with the name .modificarBrillo.sh (in my case I created it in my home folder: ~/.modificarBrillo.sh)

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    echo "ERROR: Tiene que introducir un parámetro: \"a\" para aumentar o \"d\" para disminuir"
    exit
else
    if [ "$1" != "a" ] && [ "$1" != "d" ]; then
        echo "ERROR: el parámetro de entrada sólo puede ser o \"a\" para aumentar el brillo o \"d\" para disminuirlo"
        exit
    fi
fi
MAX_BRILLO=`cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/max_brightness`
MIN_BRILLO_ABSOLUTO="0"
MIN_BRILLO="100" #el brillo mínimo puede ser 0 pero eso deja la pantalla completamente a oscuras
INTERVALO=`expr $MAX_BRILLO - $MIN_BRILLO_ABSOLUTO`
INTERVALO=`expr $INTERVALO / 10`
brillo=`cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/actual_brightness`
if [ "$1" = "a" ]; then
    let "brillo = brillo + INTERVALO"
    if [ "$brillo" -gt "$MAX_BRILLO" ]; then
    let "brillo = MAX_BRILLO"
    fi
else
    let "brillo = brillo - INTERVALO"
        if [ "$brillo" -lt "$MIN_BRILLO" ]; then
            let "brillo = MIN_BRILLO"
        fi
fi
echo "$brillo" | tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

However as the previous script needs execution permission and /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness can only be edited by root and  you have to execute in terminal:

```
chmod a+x ~/.modificarBrillo.sh
sudo chmod a+w /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`
```

The last command has to be executed every startup because the permissions of the brightness file are renewed with the startup. For doing so `sudo vim /etc/rc.local` and add the command `sudo chmod a+w /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` before the "exit 0" line

Finally you should install xbindkeys to assgin the Function key to execute the script.

In my case I add the lines to the configuration file ~/.xbindkeysrc

```
#Aumentar brillo
"/home/alvaro/.modificarBrillo.sh a"
    m:0x0 + c:233
    XF86MonBrightnessUp 

#Disminuir brillo
"/home/alvaro/.modificarBrillo.sh d"
   XF86MonBrightnessDown
```

But you could also install the program xbindkeys-config to do the proccess graphically.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, I am using Gnome3.10 in ubuntu 14.04 ( Unity). I installed tlp for temperature control in my laptop. I just removed 'tlp' and I rebooted my system and I am able to adjust screen brightness using function(fn) + arrow keys.

It might help check it once.

Answer (score 1):

Had same problem (apparently) with a Lenovo IP G50-70. - In fact, none of the function keys 'appeared' to work. Eventually in the Bios I found a 'Hotkey' enable/disable function. Paradoxically, it was 'Enabled', but this in fact enables a single key press operation for the function keys. In fact, if you use the traditional 'Fn + Function keyX' technique, they don't work.

If you 'Disable' the hotkey function in the Bios, then the function keys work 'as expected' (Fn + Function Keyx). - After doing this, all the function keys worked OK. So much for progress

Answer (score 1):

I had to add these lines to the kernel command line in the grub configuration:

```
acpi_backlight=vendor acpi_osi=linux thinkpad-acpi.brightness_enable=1
```

Note that last one. That was the one that made the brightness keys work.

Comment: This answer is lacking context. Where to put that code.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a problem on a Thinkpad W510 running kubuntu 18.04.

I found this on a Lenovo forum:

tpb - program to use the IBM ThinkPad(tm) special keys

```
sudo apt-get install tpb
```

Voila!  Brightness adjustment keys now work perfectly!  I did not even need to log out and back in.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package to deal with brightness from the command line (terminal), with the  [`xbacklight`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/xbacklight.1.html) command.

[xbacklight [image: Install xbacklight]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/xbacklight) can be installed in the Software Center. Or in the Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install xbacklight
```

you can use

- `xbacklight -inc <range from 0 to 100>`  to increase brightness with value `< ... >`
- `xbacklight -dec <range from 0 to 100>`  to decrease brightness with value `< ... >`

Comment: This one worked for me using a Thinkpad E490. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[`light`](http://haikarainen.github.io/light) by haikarainen worked for me on Xubuntu 19.10 with Thinkpad x390

With it you can adjust brightness with

```
light -A 5  # Increase brightness by 5%
light -U 5  # Decrease brightness by 5%
```