# How do you change brightness, color and sharpness from command line?

Tags: command-line, xorg, display, brightness

I am controlling my PC with SSH and scripting. How can i change the brightness, color and sharpness from command line?

Try 1: failed

```
$ sudo redshift -t 5000:5000 -g .5
Cannot list GNOME panel applets.
Initialization of gnome-clock failed.
Trying next provider...
Latitude and longitude must be set.
```

Try 2: failed

```
$ cat brightness 
20
$ cat max_brightness 
20
$ echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness 
1
$ echo 20 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

Any alternative way to do?

**Follow up**: http://jonls.dk/redshift/

```
[command]     [1000K to 10000K]       [effects 0.1 to 10.0]
|       |     /      /                /
^       ^     ^      ^                ^
redshift  -t  1000:1000   -l 0:0  -g .1; Dark
redshift  -t  1000:1000   -l 0.0  -g  5; Bright
```

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/57236/unable-to-change-brightness-in-a-lenovo-laptop/57610#57610 for changing the brightness

Comment: @Lekensteyn: please see the posted comment. Did not worked i am uing 11.04 and tried echo 0 to 20 remains same.

Comment: Note that applying gamma correction (`-g` argument to redshift) is not the same effect as adjusting the brightness (`-b`)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

If the driver of your graphics card supports it, then you can use [`xrandr`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/xrandr.1.html).

The following command lists the current configuration:

```
xrandr --current --verbose
```

If you want to change the configuration of an output, then you need the name of the output. This name is part of the output of `xrandr --current`, for example `LVDS1`.

The brightness can be changed like this:

```
xrandr --output <outputname> --brightness 0.8
```

Gamma (**red**:**green**:**blue**):

```
xrandr --output <outputname> --gamma 0.5:1.0:1.0
```

Comment: this works, FYI: newer laptops use eDP

Comment: I found I didn't need to use the `verbose` option.

Comment: It would be helpful to see an example of output for
"xrandr --output <outputname> --brightness 0.8"

Comment: doesn't change brightness for me.

Comment: for me neither.

Comment: This has brightness and gamma, is there also such thing as `white balance` / `color temperature` ?

Comment: if i change the values through the command xrandr --output DP-1 --gamma 1.0:1.0:1.0 , 
works fine for but just for one second, then it comes back to default value 1.0:1.0:1.0

Comment: @hydroxide the command just returns status; there's no text output on success.  On failure, the return is set to non-zero and you may get output.  I get:  ```james@gig ~ $ xrandr --output DP-0 --brightness 0.8
james@gig ~ $ echo $?
0
james@gig ~ $ xrandr --output notAMonitor --brightness 0.8
warning: output notAMonitor not found; ignoring
xrandr: Need crtc to set gamma on.
james@gig ~ $ echo $?
1
``` And if it works, I see the brightness of my monitors decrease.

Answer (score 22):

xrandr will not increase the screen brightness on the hardware level (the one that is changed by the laptop display brightness keys). As the xrandr manual says:

> --brightness *brightness*
>
> Multiply the gamma values on
> the crtc currently attached to the output to specified
> floating value. Useful for overly bright or overly dim
> outputs. However, this is a software only modification, if
> your hardware has support to actually change the brightness,
> you will probably prefer to use xbacklight.

Instead, use `xbacklight` to change the brightness:

```
xbacklight -get #get the current level
xbacklight -set *percent* #set brightness to a given percentage
xbacklight -inc *percent* #increase by a given percentage
xbacklight -dec *percent* #decrease by a given percentage
```

However, since this is same as using the laptop brightness keys, this cannot go beyond the limits of 0-100%. If you wish to brighten/darken your screen further than that limit, you can use xrandr to force software brightness levels:

```
xrandr --output LVDS1 --brightness 0.5
```

Note that `xrandr` accepts fractions (0.0-1.0) while `xbacklight` accepts percentages(0-100)

Comment: In my case, the `xrandr --output eDP1 --brightness 0.2` approach works fine while `xbacklight -set 20` fails.

Comment: ***accepts fractions (0.0-1.0)*** is misleading. For my external TB3 DisplayPort  to HDMI this worked fine: `xrandr --output DP-1-1  --brightness 1.2`

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Yes, setting it >1.0 crops the display gamut in exchange for overall brightness increase.  In other words you lose details in bright areas.

Comment: Is this related to the temperature of the monitor? I mean, with `xrandr` darker should it be colder than using some other tool? I'm afraid that my monitor is too warm.

Comment: @sigur temp colour is relative weighting of red / blue curves, `--gamma` can be used to tweak it a bit. I think you'd need to poke at the LUT to get finer tuning if the monitor has no settings you can use.

Answer (score 6):

For laptops, I just learned from `man xrandr`:

```
   --brightness brightness
          Multiply  the gamma values on the crtc currently attached to the
          output to specified floating value. Useful for overly bright  or
          overly  dim outputs.  However, this is a software only modifica‐
          tion, if your  hardware  has  support  to  actually  change  the
          brightness, you will probably prefer to use xbacklight.
```

So I tried

```
xbacklight -get
xbacklight -set 70
```

and it works!

Comment: This post is from 2013. I can't make it work with my current laptop either....

Answer (score 5):

If you're using redshift, you need to give it your latitude and longitude so it knows when time of day changes. Something like

```
redshift -t 5000:5000 -l 55.7:12.6 -g .5
```

Though it may be a bit unconventional use of redshift :)

Also, it works fine without sudo.

Comment: +1 that really did a small trick. But really i am looking for same way more RAW brightness + color + gamma tuning.

Answer (score 3):

I use this script to set brightness on all of my displays at once:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
if [ -z $1 ]; then
    echo "Usage: brighntess BRIGHTNESS"
    echo "BRIGHTNESS is a float (0.0-1.0)"
else
    xrandr --listmonitors | grep "^ " | cut -f 6 -d' ' | \
    xargs --replace=MONITOR xrandr --output MONITOR --brightness $1
fi
```

Comment: xrandr isnt working

Comment: See `xrandr --output $(xrandr --listmonitors | sed -ne 's/ .* //gp') --brightness $1`

Answer (score 1):

Change VGA-1 with your device

```
xrandr --listmonitors
Monitors: 1
```

0: +*VGA-1 1366/410x768/230+0+0  **VGA-1**

```
xrandr --output VGA-1  --brightness 1   (for 100% brightness)
xrandr --output VGA-1  --brightness 1.5 (for 150% brightness)
xrandr --output VGA-1  --brightness 2   (for 200% or double brightness)
xrandr --output VGA-1  --brightness 4 (for 400% brightness)
```

Careful with 0 (you'll need to restart Xorg):

```
xrandr --output VGA-1  --brightness 0 (for Blank Screen)

xrandr --output VGA-1  --brightness 0.8 (for 80% brightness)
```

This works on normal lcd/led monitors as they do not support hardware brightness like laptops do.

Comment: Does nothing. Doesnt change brightness

Answer (score 0):

There's also [DDC/CI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_Data_Channel#DDC.2FCI), and linux client: [ddccontrol](https://github.com/ddccontrol/ddccontrol) (and, gddccontrol for GUI).

Tt's in official ubuntu repository:

```
sudo apt install ddccontrol ddccontrol-db gddccontrol
```

Comment: No monitor supporting DDC/CI available.

Answer (score 0):

for monitor brightness, in gnome try https://github.com/fastrizwaan/gnome-set-brightness

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.a11y.magnifier mag-factor 1
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.a11y.magnifier brightness-red -0.5
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.a11y.magnifier brightness-green -0.5
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.a11y.magnifier brightness-blue -0.5
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.a11y.applications screen-magnifier-enabled true
```