# How do I decrease brightness of my laptop beyond the amount it specifies?

Tags: brightness, colors

Is there a way I can decrease the brightness of my laptop (Dell 1558) beyond the amount it actually allows me to?

I tried **Redshift**, it works okay, but I wanted to manually decrease the brightness. There was an app I came across in Windows named **Dimmer** and it worked perfectly, but I couldn't find its Ubuntu counterpart.

Comment: Some useful answers to this question [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/282201/17164).

Answer (score 3):

For regular operation on your backlight you can use `xrandr` and `xbacklight`, but that will not get beyond its regular limits.

Try to find your kernel's backlight interface.

```
find /sys -name "*backlight*"
```

For my system, it is provided in the `/sys/class/backlight/nvidia_backlight` folder where I can use the files

- `actual_brightness`
- `bl_power`
- `brightness`
- `max_brightness`

to test things out. For example:

```
# cat max_brightness 
127
# cat actual_brightness 
127
# echo 60 > brightness # <-- here it actually decreases my backlight
# cat actual_brightness 
59
```

If you're using an nVidia GPU you could try out [`nvidiabl`](https://github.com/guillaumezin/nvidiabl) or even patch the source in [`nvidiabl-laptops.h`](https://github.com/guillaumezin/nvidiabl/blob/master/nvidiabl-laptops.h) to override default min/max values to fit your needs.

*However -- keep in mind that forcing it beyond its limits may damage your hardware.*

Answer (score 1):

The question has been answered here:
[How do you change brightness, color and sharpness from command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62249/how-do-you-change-brightness-color-and-sharpness-from-command-line)

On my Dell laptop:

```
xrandr --output LVDS1 --brightness 0.8
```

You can run the `xrandr` command to see the name of your screens.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.iasptk.com/save-screen-brightness-settings-in-ubuntu-1204-laptop

Some Ubuntu laptops screen brightness reset to the lowest or highest on every boot and you have to configure the screen birghtness on every login.

To save the screen brightness settings in Ubuntu laptop.

Open a terminal window, and execute this command to edit /etc/rc.local:

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

**Add this before the last line “exit 0″:**

```
echo 5 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

number 5 is the value of your screen brightness. With this command check the maximum:

```
cat /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/max_brightness
```