# Setting a display's backlight brightness to be lower than is possible via the normal brightness controls

Tags: display

By normal brightness controls I mean the accelerators on my laptop's keyboard that seem to integrate with Unity.

In a dark room, my screen is quite bright, even on the lowest setting. Can I override this?

I tried setting it explicitly via both:

```
sudo echo 500 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/actual_brightness
sudo echo 500 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/actual_brightness
```

But I get a `permission denied` error.

When at the lower bounds via my keyboard's brighness controls, `acpi_video0/actual_brightness` is 0, and `intel_backlight/actual_brightness` is 729. Can I set the latter value to be even lower?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your command gives elevated permissions to the echo command (which doesn't need them), but not to the part that redirects the output stream to the root-owned file (which does)

In a terminal, you can either do

```
echo 7 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

which gives the elevated permission to the bit that really needs it, or

```
sudo sh -c "echo 7 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness"
```

which runs the whole command in a sudo shell

Answer (score 1):

I created a slider tool based on the information presented here in the question/answers:

- https://github.com/oblitum/backlight.

It provides an alternative slider to control backlight with finer control.

Comment: Looks good @chico!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the two items I show in the question are read only for all users.

However `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` is not. So, the following works:

```
sudo su
echo 500 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

Be aware that echoing a zero value makes the screen is unreadable :)

You may have a different name for your device (instead of `intel_backlight`).

Also, performing the above using `sudo echo ...` doesn't work. Can someone explain why I have to do `sudo su` first?

**EDIT** [@Vivek's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/367706/17164) explains this.