# How to change color balance of the monitor

Tags: laptop, display

I'd like to change the default (white) color on my laptop display. Right now the color is too blue-like, the best comparison I can make is that it emits color similar to Xenon lights on cars.

I have tried to use gnome-color-manager, but it only shows the light curves, it doesn't allow any modification, except for loading the icm profile. I don't have any calibration hardware, but since I don't use this machine for graphic design I don't care if the colors are correct, I just don't want them to be Xenony. It tires my eyes.

I also tried to use redshift, but it only changes the gamma, I tried lprof but got reaally confused by the GUI :) I just need some kind of slider where I could change the color balances just like in some Gimp, not only for the image but for the entire display.

External big displays usually have some buttons to set this, but it is not available on my laptop.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you change brightness, color and sharpness from command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62249/how-do-you-change-brightness-color-and-sharpness-from-command-line)

Answer (score 0):

Well this is not exactly what you are asking for but it can still help.

My sugestion if for you to get the f.lux software.

Quoting their [website](http://justgetflux.com/) f.lux,

> makes the color of your computer's display adapt to the time of day, warm at night and like sunlight during the day.

your eyes will live again ;)