# Artificially increase maximum screen brightness

Tags: 16.04, display, laptop, brightness

I have my laptop set to maximum brightness, but it's not bright enough.  Is it possible to somehow make it brighter?

Comment: Check this topic, maybe it will help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/62249/how-do-you-change-brightness-color-and-sharpness-from-command-line

Comment: not sure if this helps, but `xrandr --output <screen_name> --brightness 1.1` does that, but the screen usually looks ugly then. Retrieve `<screen_name>` from the output of `xrandr`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Run this to see a list of your outputs. You're looking for the one that is "connected":

```
xrandr --current
```

Here's a screenshot of my list. The output I want is the "connected" `eDP1` at the top:

[image]

Now you can run these commands to make adjustments. Replace `eDP1` with the name of your output, and change `1.2` to make the adjustments:

```
xrandr --output eDP1 --brightness 1.2
# Note: 1 is default
```

You can also use `gamma` instead of `brightness`:

```
xrandr --output <outputname> --gamma 0.5:1.0:1.0
# Note: 1.0:1.0:1.0 is default
```

Comment: You should not add other information in the middle of your code, it breaks the code and when people copy it, it simply won't work. I have edited it but be careful not to break your code.

Comment: @MarkKirby Thanks for pointing out that mistake. I will make sure not to do that again.

Comment: @Hizqeel, I get the following: `userone@laptop:~$ xrandr --output DVI-0 --brightness 2
warning: output DVI-0 not found; ignoring
xrandr: Need crtc to set gamma on.
userone@laptop:~$ 
`

Comment: @oshirowanen you obviously didn't read the comment to  your question. DVI-0 is not the name of your screen.

Comment: @oshirowanen I have updated the answer. If this is clear and solves your problem then let me know.

Comment: Thanks, how do I figure out what the default value was?  2 is way to bright and makes the text look bad.  Currently have set it to 1.

Comment: @oshirowanen 1 is the default, I would try 1.1 for a start.

Comment: This was very helpful thankyou. Is there any software available that would make it easier to try different settings?

Comment: In my case (using Ubuntu 17.10) the commands didn't make any change.

Answer (score 1):

use both of them

```
xrandr |grep " connected" |cut -f1 -d " "
```

get the name that listed and use it instead of eDP-1

```
 xrandr --output eDP-1 --brightness 1.4
```