# How to control the RGB components for gamma+brightness+contrast from command line?

Tags: command-line, nvidia, brightness, contrast, gamma

I saw this on nVidia application. We can control, for each component of RGB, these 3 values: gamma, brightness and contrast (below showing only for Red component):

[image]

So, I want to know if we can access these 3 controls for each component from the command line.

I already know about `xgamma` but what about brightness and contrast for each component?

I think these answers are near what I need, but I can't find a way to do exactly what I ask by using these tips:

[How do you change brightness colour and sharpness from command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62249/how-do-you-change-brightness-color-and-sharpness-from-command-line)
[Is there a software utility to adjust screen gamma brightness contrast](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9248/is-there-a-software-utility-to-adjust-screen-gamma-brightness-contrast)

Comment: well... the quite obvious answer (for nvidia users) is to direcly modify the config rc text file, and load it from the command line with `nvidia-settings -l` :)

Comment: I found one command that deals with the 3 components. `xcalib`. But that requires icc profile to modify and load. but couldn't get that worked for me

Comment: @Anwar it seems to require an icc profile file, could be because my monitor is CRT?

Comment: My monitor is not CRT, but here is same. However I saw KDE have GUI method for doing these. You can try with a Live Kubuntu. But didn't change anything in my external monitor. May be because it's external

Comment: @Anwar kde settings gives access to hardware display, but there was nothing about brightness etc, whas there you mean? or some specific kde aplication?