# 18.04: Dell laptop, cannot adjust screen brightness

Tags: 18.04, display, dell, screen, brightness

I installed ubuntu 18.04 on my dell XPS laptop but for some reason the screen brightness buttons don't work.

My laptop model is XPS 15 7590 with a NVIDIA(R) GeForce(R) GTX 1650 4GB GDDR5 video card.

I have found a solution by executing the "xrandr --output eDP -1 --brightness ".  But this is a bit too hacky for me and not practical.

Does anyone have any workarounds for this?

Thanks
-N

Comment: There are many models of XPS laptops. Please browse to https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04?app=products and provide Dell the information so their website can identify which you have, then return here with that Model Part Number, click [edit], and add it to your question.

Comment: @K7AAY, added that info as you requested, thx.

Comment: Have you tried xbacklight? See <https://askubuntu.com/a/149265/832813>.

Comment: @Quasímodo, I tried and didn't work and people are suggesting using xrandr command which as I stated does work.  But all these solutions are command line and quite hacky.  How can I control the brightness via the OS UI elements designed for this purpose?

Comment: 1. Sometimes the piece of software responsible for making it available through UI won't find the way to change brightness, as is your case.
2. `xrandr` does not change brightness on hardware level <https://askubuntu.com/a/189308/832813>. 
3. Try the method described here <https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/485263> to really change your brightness. If it works and you have trouble converting that into a more convenient UI solution, I suggest researching and then, if necessary, opening a question.