# No brightness control, HP dv3500 laptop / GeForce GPU

Tags: laptop, hp, brightness

I feel almost stupid asking a brightness question with all the similar ones out there, but I haven't yet found a working solution, so here goes:

### System

HP dv3500 series laptop (dv3550eo - Scandinavian version) with a GeForce 9300M GS graphics card, drivers version 280.13 running on Ubuntu 11.10.

The system keys for changing brightness are Fn+F7 and Fn+F8, respectively, but nothing happens - I can't change the brightness.

A few of the tricks I've tried:

- The same tricks this Lenovo owner tried: [Unable to change brightness in a Lenovo laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57236/unable-to-change-brightness-in-a-lenovo-laptop)
- this: http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11543948&postcount=40
- Triedls /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
- also for acpi_video1 and acpi_video2. Nothing was found for any of them.

I'm guessing it's a driver problem, but I've already installed the nvidia drivers (there was a popup upon first restart after install).

I apologize in advance for not reiterating the rest of the suggested fixes I've tried, as they are too numerous for me to remember, and have frankly left me exhausted.

I hope a user with a similar computer to mine has found a fix, elsewise I fear this shall be the fourth time over the years I've given Linux a crack only to give it up again within a fortnight :-/

Fingers crossed for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Please try `smartdimmer`.
I've succeeded using it via command line, now looking a way to bind it to <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>f7</kbd> and <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>f8</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

Open `/etc/default/grub` with your favorite text editor, ie `gedit`

> gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub

Look for the line

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

and add *acpi_backlight=vendor* to it so that it reads

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"`

Update grub to include the changes done

```
sudo update-grub
```

Reboot

```
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggetion. I've tried that one as well, but it doesn't solve the problem for me.