# screen brightness and keyboard backlight works in unity, not in kde

Tags: kubuntu, brightness

i have ubuntu 12.04 and sony laptop, and i've installed nvidia driver. screen brightness changing (with keyboard fn keys) and keyboard backlight works in unity, but it doesn't in kde. when i issue the command:
    `echo 8 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness`
it changes brightness, but it doesn't anything when i press brightness functions keys, even displaying a bar.
and also when i enter:
`echo 1 > /sys/devices/platform/sony-laptop/kbd_backlight`
it turns on keyboard backlight but it is not turned on by default. the best practice is what happens in windows: turn it on when you're in a dark place, using a light sensor.

thanx for your help ;)

Comment: You might want to look at [**this answer**](http://askubuntu.com/a/58088/3268), starting from #4.

Comment: it won't work since `lsmod | grep ^i915` doesn't output anything.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot mate,this command :

```
echo 8 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

Helped me change brightness levels in Kubuntu, however in Ubuntu <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys work quite fine after adding Option Registry Dwords..... line in `xorg.conf`. As of now,I will make a small script to work with Kubuntu, but we need the <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys to be working for many people who don't want to be running scripts all the time for such a simple task.