# Not able to change brightness [12.04]

Tags: 12.04, display, brightness

I can't change my brighness via the default ubuntu tool or my FN keys, or even xbacklight.
I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 on a laptop with a dual graphics (AMD HD6770M+Intel). I've the drivers set up properly and I can switch between them.

I've tried to adjust the brightness on both the integrated and discrete GPU. Nothing happens.

Any clue how do I go ahead fixing this? I've tried every solution here: [Unable to change brightness in a Lenovo laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57236/unable-to-change-brightness-in-a-lenovo-laptop)

Answer (score 0):

Use Brightness Controller(https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/brightness-controller/). It should work.

Answer (score 0):

press ctrl+t to open the terminal. In the terminal:
    cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
will tell you your screen brightness, then you can change it with:

```
sudo su -c "echo 72 >/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness"
```

Replacing 72 with your desired screen brightness. It will reset when you reboot, but you could just create a text file with the command and run it every time you boot until you find a better solution.