# How to change screen brightness from commandline on Asus X453?

Tags: laptop, brightness

I'm using the Fluxbox window manager on Ubuntu 12.04.  I recently got my desktop into a strange situation, and I'm not sure how!  The situation was this:

- If I close the laptop screen lid and then re-open it, brightness is greatly reduced.
- If I run `pm-suspend` and then wake the machine, brightness goes back to full!

So I have a rather inconvenient way to control my brightness, but I wonder if there might be a better way?!

But I'm not actually sure what caused my machine to get into this state to begin with!  (I initially thought it was from running `gnome-settings-daemon` but I haven't been able to reproduce it since rebooting.)

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 with a 3.5.0 kernel.  (Because I've had trouble getting later kernels, and Ubuntu 14 and 15, to boot or run well.)

---

I have tried [other](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57236/unable-to-change-brightness-in-a-lenovo-laptop/57610) [tips](https://askubuntu.com/questions/149054/how-to-change-lcd-brightness-from-command-line-or-via-script) on this site, but none of them worked.

- `xbacklight -get` responds with exit code 0 but no data. `-inc` and `-dec` do nothing.
- `find /sys/ | grep brightness` gives me:

  ```
  /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:02:00.0/leds/ath9k-phy0/brightness
  /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:02:00.0/leds/ath9k-phy0/max_brightness
  /sys/module/i915/parameters/invert_brightness
  /sys/module/video/parameters/brightness_autoswitch_via_bios
  /sys/module/video/parameters/brightness_switch_enabled
  ```

  but poking values into those files did nothing.
- And likewise for `find /sys/ | grep backlight`

  ```
  /sys/class/backlight     (empty folder)
  /sys/module/video/parameters/use_bios_initial_backlight
  ```
- `xrandr` did nothing with `-gamma` or `-brightness`.  (I am running a generic graphics driver with no acceleration: "Mesa Project and SGI" / `.../drivers/gpu/drm/i915/i915.ko`)
- I do have the kernel module `i915 530857  0` but Oleph's [script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57236/unable-to-change-brightness-in-a-lenovo-laptop/57610#58088) didn't help.
- I tried the [`indicator-brightness`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57236/unable-to-change-brightness-in-a-lenovo-laptop/57610#451780) package to no avail.

Comment: "but I ran gnome-settings-daemon in order to change the font sizes for Google Chrome, and as a result strange things started happening when running on battery" so if you _don't_ run gnome-settings-daemon, all is well except for Chrome's font size?

Comment: You were right to question. I have been unable to reproduce the behaviour by running `gnome-settings-daemon` so I'm not sure what caused the odd behaviour in the first place. I will edit the question.

Comment: Please join me in **voting to close my question** as "unclear". Because I was not able to reproduce the problem, and now I never will, because I have since moved to Ubuntu 14.04 and a newer kernel, where brightness controls are working as expected. Thanks!