# Lenovo Laptop: Cannot change screen brightness

Tags: laptop, lenovo, brightness

I havent found a solution so far for my problem after researching for hours and hours..

Basically my Laptop Screen is really really bright and I cannot turn it down with the fn keys. Although they show the sun and the value bar going up or down it does not change the brightness itself.

I am having this issue on any OS running.
This is really unpractical as it drains the battery quicker and is really unconfortable to look at at night.

Comment: Did you check out the answers at http://askubuntu.com/q/57236/367990 already?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add following line to `/etc/default/grub`

```
acpi_backlight=none
```

and then update the grub with following command

```
sudo update-grub
```