# Can't control Screen Brightness in (K) Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: screen, brightness, intel, 16.10

I can't change my screen brightness in (K) ubuntu 16.10
I have a Samsung AtivBook 6. My Fn keys is working, but only appears the brightness bar on the screen, but don't change the brightness.

My notebook specs:
Intel i5 3230M;
Graphics: Intel HD 4000 (Onboard);
AMD Radeon HD 8850M (Offboard);

Anyone have a solution?

Thanks

Comment: You should look up your stuff first, and if my answer was helpful please press the check-mark beside it!

Comment: Ok  buddy :) @UbuntuUser

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that you didn't have the slider not working, but still it was easy to find the answer.

Comment: Hey, by the way, go to general chat and I will post it. You won't be able to chat though!

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room

Comment: Please add the output `lspci -nnk | grep "VGA" -A2` and `ls /sys/class/backlight/` to your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to change brightness in a Lenovo laptop](http://askubuntu.com/questions/57236/unable-to-change-brightness-in-a-lenovo-laptop)