# How to dim OLED laptop screen?

Tags: display, laptop, screen, brightness

I have x1 yoga OLED and screen is always at max brightness. From what I've read since it's OLED the usual dimming doesn't work but this command is needed:

```
xrandr --output eDP1 --brightness .5
```

warning: output eDP1 not found;

ignoring xrandr: Need crtc to set gamma on

Answer (score 1):

OLED brightness on linux has been hit & miss for the past 4 years or so (since OLED came to laptops).

There are numerous ways to set OLED brightness manually, here's the ones I found more useful:

```
xrandr --output $oled_screen --brightness $percent
```

$percent is a value between 0.0 and 1.0, $oled_screen is your oled panel screen name. To get a list of attached screens run xrandr without any arguments.

```
redshift -m randr:screen=$oled_screen -P -O $temperature -b $percent
```

This is an example of how to manually set brightness and night light filter. $oled_screen is the same as above, $temperature is the color temperature of the display (6500 for normal, unaltered colors, 3500 is a usual value for a night filter), $percent is a value between 0.1 and 1.0  and it specifies the brightness of the display. It acts the same as when using xrandr, but redshift prevents you from setting values lower than 0.1 while xrandr allows even values of 0.0 (pitch black)

```
redshift -P -O $temperature -b $percent
```

Same as above, but changes will be applied to all screens. Useful if you don't want to look for screen names when you only have 1 screen anyway.

Anyway, I doubt you are just looking for "how to set brightness using a command" and would appreciate a solution that "just works" on your shiny amazing OLED display. [This repsository](https://github.com/lawleagle/oled-linux) is probably the solution you are looking for. It "just works" in most cases, and with little tweaking you can get the brightness control similar to how it works out of the box on LCD displays. There is also a comprehensive documentation in README.md

Answer (score 0):

I know is an old post but I was having the same issue with a Gigabyte OLED laptop.

Your command is almost good except for the `eDP1`. If you  run `xrandr` without arguments, you should find a line with something similar to `eDP`. In my case was `eDP-1-1`. Try running your command with this new name. It worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

`xrandr --verbose |egrep '(Bright|Gamma)'`

then

`xrandr --output VGA1  --brightness .75`

Alternatively

`echo "7" > brightness` where 7 is the brightness value obtained from

`# cat brightness`

Comment: doesnt work either 
user@computer:~$ xrandr --verbose |egrep '(Bright|Gamma)'
 Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0
 Brightness: 1.0
user@computer:~$ xrandr --output VGA1  --brightness .75
warning: output VGA1 not found; ignoring
xrandr: Need crtc to set gamma on.
user@computer:~$ echo "7" > brightness where 7 is the brightness value obtained from # cat brightness
user@computer:~$ echo "7" > brightness where 7 is the brightness value obtained from # cat brightness
user@computer:~$ xrandr --verbose |egrep '(Bright|Gamma)' Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0
 Brightness: 1.0
user@computer:~$

Comment: I fixed the command , also try checking here: http://askubuntu.com/q/57236/653540

Comment: The command seems the same?

However, still doesn't work :(

Comment: By the way which graphics card do you use?

Comment: Intel® HD Graphics 520 (Skylake GT2)

Comment: Have you tried this already: `echo 400 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` ?

Comment: outputs 400 but doesn't help either :(