# How to list recursive file sizes of files and directories in a directory?

Tags: files, file-size

How do I list all the files in a directory and their recursive file sizes?

---edit

I want to see the sizes 'rolled up' to the parent directories in the directory listed. I don't want to see the child directories or their contents or sizes.

Comment: You mean that you want to see the total size (sum) of all the files in a folder, like right-clicking on a folder on your desktop and selecting 'properties' ?

Comment: Are you looking for software which helps you to find big files, or something to get a (collapsable) file tree?

Comment: Hi @Pavlos G - I mean the sum for each of the directories in the directory I'm currently in - not the sum for the overall directory.

Comment: @J G - Check my update ;-)

Answer (score 71, accepted):

I guess the easiest way is by typing `ls -l`, or `ls -lh` which will provide the file size in human-readable format (KB, MB, etc).

If 'recursively' means listing all the subsequent folders, e.g.:

/foo/
/foo/bar/
....

Then you should also add parameter `R`, like `ls -lR` or `ls -lhR`

More information for `ls` can be found by typing `man ls`

Update:

The following command as Lekensteyn proposed will probably do the job:

`du -h --max-depth=1 <folder>`

`-h` is for human-readable
`--apparent-size` is another way to display sizes as already stated
`--max-depth` is the level of subfolders you want to go down to.

Comment: What to use for max depth? -1?

Answer (score 90):

```
apt-get install ncdu
```

[image]

It is interactive too so if you want to check on a sub folder just UP, DOWN, and Enter to it.

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Thank you very much!

Comment: Maybe the most amazing software recommendation I have ever got

Comment: this should be the approved answer

Comment: `ncdu` is really so underrated

Answer (score 37):

To get the total size of a directory and all children

```
du -hs directory/*
```

Comment: I'd like the next level down from that - the recursive sizes of all the first level children.

Comment: I'll edit my answer. You need to use du -h directory/*

Answer (score 17):

Also check out `tree`. It is not installed by default but is the repositories.

Example:

```
richard@legend:~$ tree Applications/ -s
Applications/
├── [           4096]  AlexFTPS-1.0.2
│   ├── [      31232]  AlexPilotti.FTPS.Client.dll
│   ├── [     274432]  C5.dll
│   ├── [       1457]  C5-License
│   ├── [      35147]  COPYING
│   ├── [       7639]  COPYING.LESSER
│   ├── [         70]  ftps
│   ├── [      28672]  ftps.exe
│   ├── [      98304]  Plossum CommandLine.dll
│   ├── [       1557]  Plossum-License
│   └── [       2560]  README
└── [           4096]  src
    └── [     180849]  AlexFTPS_bin_1.0.2.zip
```

More options can be found in the man page.

Comment: Should sizes be shown?

Comment: J G: The -s shows the sizes.

Comment: Shows the size of the directory record rather than full directory size.

Comment: `-h` show size in human readable way, e.g `tree -s`

Answer (score 17):

Since you don't specifically mention you need a terminal-based solution, I think **baobab** a.k.a. Disk Usage Analyzer is missing from the list.

It is installed in Ubuntu by default and does exactly what you want in a nice graphical UI with the ability to drill down the directory hierarchy.

Apart from displaying a list of directories with their sizes, it is also showing a rings or treemap chart of filesystem usage, which is extremely useful for visualising the directories which take up the most space.

[image: baobab the Disk Usage Analyzer]

Answer (score 11):

A [terminal solution](https://askubuntu.com/q/38162/6969) is the `du` command:

```
du --all --human-readable --apparent-size
```

(shorthand: `du -ah --apparent-size`)

`du` displays the disk usage for each file and directory. The options explained:

- `--all`, `-a` - show sizes for files as well, not just directories
- `--human-readable`, `-h` - show sizes in a human readable format, e.g. `10K` (10 kilobytes), `10` (10 bytes)
- `--apparent-size` - show the actual file size, not the sizes as used by the disk.

Comment: I just wanted the first-level children

Comment: @hawkeye for 1st level you can use `--max-depth=1`

Comment: @nikoskip nice tip! Also nice to know is the shorthand, `--max-depth=1` can be shortened to `-d1`.

Comment: how to get all of these in a decending order of size..

Comment: how do I view the contents and empty : /dev/sda5 ext4 430G 381G 27G 94% / my laptop is less than 1 month old and it is so full which it makes no sense

Answer (score 3):

This seems to do the trick when simlinks are involved.

```
ls -LRlh
```

Comment: given answer didnt give me details for simlinks(ls -lhR), the numbers listed next to it didnt correspond to the right size of each of the values either. My answer gave me a hierarchy with a defined tree structure and the correct answer....OR are you referring to some other upvoted answer?

Comment: Down-vote retracted, upvoted.  Please [edit] and put the comment in the answer...  Thanks for the explanation.  **;-)**

Answer (score 1):

To get a sorted list put everything in MB and sort :

```
du -m * | sort -n
```

Or use tool such as [DiskReport](http://www.diskreport.net) to generate a report of full disk tree.

Answer (score 0):

Another terminal solution with `find` and sort (by filesize, column 1)

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 ! -path . -printf "%s %p\n" | sort -n -k1                              
178 ./somefile.txt
219 ./somefile2.txt
4096 ./c
4096 ./cs2
4096 ./perl
4096 ./python
4096 ./random
4096 ./sh
```

Comment: This doesn't show the size of the directory.

Comment: 4K is not the sizes of the directories

Answer (score 0):

I like the following approach:

```
du -schx .[!.]* * | sort -h
```

where:

- `s`:  display only a total for each argument
- `c`:  produce a grand total
- `h`:  print sizes in a human-readable format
- `x`:  skip directories on different file systems
- `.[!.]* *`: Summarize disk usage of each file, recursively for directories (including "hidden" ones)
- `| sort -h`: Sort based on human-readable numbers (e.g., 2K 1G)

Answer (score -1):

For listing size of folder contents with less typing (`-d` is short for `--max-depth`)

```
du -hd1
```