# I was told on Launchpad to test a mainline Kernel. How do I do that (with NVIDIA drivers)?

Tags: kernel, mainline-kernel

I am coming from Bug [# 868950](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/868950) on launchpad, a kernel related problem. To analyse the problem a bit deeper and see where it comes from, I was told to try out a mainline kernel to see if the problem persists.

It would be great if the person to answer this question could post a step-by-step guide on what to do. It would also be nice to explain why this is required and how exactly this helps the developers. I couldn't find any proper documentation on this for newbies. I'm sure this way more people will find themselves able to help out and we'll eventually do the devs a favor.
Note that I have to use NVIDIA drivers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mainline kernels are compiled from recent sources using the Ubuntu configuration, so any bugfixes will first appear in the mainline kernel. Since the kernel package receives a lot of bug reports, the developer team cannot spend a lot time on all bug reports. Your reported bug may be fixed before, so that's why they tell you to test it with the most recent kernel.

To install a mainline kernel:

1. Find the latest kernel on http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/?C=M;O=D. At the moment, it's http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.1-rc9-oneiric/
2. Create a new directory for saving the downloaded kernel packages (e.g. `~/kernel-test`)
3. Download the `linux-headers*_amd64.deb`, `linux-headers*_all.deb` and `linux-image*_amd64.deb` files.   Replace `amd64` by `i386` if you're running a 32-bit OS, and pick the "pae" version if you want it.  You can check if you're running pae now by looking in /proc/cpuinfo.
4. [Open a terminal](https://askubuntu.com/q/38162/6969) and install the downloaded kernel packages:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i ~/kernel-test/*.deb
   ```
5. Reboot and the new kernel will automatically be selected. If it won't boot, either try pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd> or using the power button. The next boot, the menu will appear. If not, hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> after the BIOS POST.

To uninstall the mainline kernel, simply uninstall the related packages:

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-headers-3*-generic linux-image-3*-generic
```

Replace `*` by the package names of the mainline kernels. It matches the file you've downloaded.

Be aware that the mainline builds are compiled with an older toolset which has some side-effects like being unable to unload kernel modules after loading them (this applies to DKMS packages like `nvidia-current`)

Comment: So will this work with my nvidia card, using nvidia-current?

Comment: Where did you install your nvidia driver from? If from the official repositories (or a PPA), it should not be an issue. However, if using the ones from nvidia.com, the driver might not work. By the way, is your card a Quadro 1000M? Your bugreport is about sound, is that related to this question?

Comment: I installed them using jockey! My card is a Quadro 2000M. That has to do with yet another bug which I was asked to instal a mainline kernel for.

Comment: The Quadro 2000M is from the [NVC0](http://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/CodeNames#NVC0) family. That is an Optimus model. See [How well do laptops with Nvidia Optimus work?](http://askubuntu.com/q/36930/6969) for ways to use your nvidia card. I guess that your graphical effects are currently broken?

Comment: No my graphics work just fine. I also tried out your procedure and it worked as well. However, the new kernel version does not boot on my computer. Could you add to your answer how to revert the state again?

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: On the wiki, they insist in removing the nVidia drivers if no package is available in the kernel you want to test. When I installed Ubuntu, the nVidia drivers where installed automatically for my nVidia GeForce GTX 960M. Do I assume that a newer kernel will cope and I don't need to remove the drivers before installation?