# Trust GXT18 Keyboard not working (HID_MAX_USAGES)

Tags: keyboard

I'm an owner of a Trust GXT 18 keyboard that doesn’t work with Linux.. I've read around the internet, that if I increase the HID_MAX_USAGES (something to do with usb devices) I could get it to work, so the question is:

How can I increase it?

If you see another solution, please tell me, because I don't want to mess around system commands unless if is the only way to get it working!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no way around (at least that I know of) other than installing a newer kernel until Ubuntu uses a 3.6 kernel.

See this page for more information: [Linux support for the Trust GXT 18 keyboard](https://skip.org/misc/trust-gxt-18-keyboard-linux.html)

Comment: Installing a newer-than-Ubuntu-stable kernel is not that hard and does not require compiling (edited your post). See [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/65662/88802) on how to install precompiled kernels from `http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa`. Also, Ubuntu *does* backport fixes to the stable kernels. Feel free to open a bug report to get this fix included in the Ubuntu stable kernels.