# iPhone mount errors

Tags: 11.10, mount, iphone

When I plug my iPhone (iOS 5) into my laptop with Ubuntu 11.10, I get this error:

> Unable to mount Documents on iPhone. Location is already mounted

followed by this error:

> Unable to mount iPhone. Location is already mounted

After I see these errors, the "Documents on iPhone" folder pops up. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install libimobiledevice-utils;idevicepair unpair && idevicepair pair
```

Comment: While this may technically answer the question, could you also include what these commands do in [a terminal](http://askubuntu.com/questions/38162/what-is-the-terminal)?

Answer (score 9):

@Lekensteyn - here is a simple description of these commands do:

1. download and install library 'libimobiledevice-utils' from known sources

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libimobiledevice-utils
   ```
2. and once done

   ```
   ;
   ```
3. unmount and mount your iPhone

   ```
   idevicepair unpair && idevicepair pair
   ```

Running a command with sudo will require you to have root access rights and you'll be prompted to input password for root user. So technically it may not be possible in a corporate/locked-down environment where users are not deemed to have root access.

Comment: This worked but only when I did `slide to unlock` -> `enter 4 digit pin` before #3, as stated on this [ubuntuforum](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1861617&page=4)

Comment: Sorry I am new to Ubuntu and step 2 and 3 I am not sure what to do ? After I enter( sudo apt-get install libimobiledevice-utils ) then hit enter then do I type in ( ;) then enter again and type in( idevicepair unpair && idevicepair pair) ?
I am running Ubuntu 14.4 . Would I be better off to find out how to purchase the latest version of Ubuntu ? Would I be able to connect my iPhone 6 and download the photos I have into UBUNTU ? My computer is a HP Laptop running 32bit.
Thank you for your Time Isaiah