# Ubuntu 14.04 Unable to mount iphone. Cant close window

Tags: iphone

Sometimes when I plug my iPhone in to my computer I get the following error:

```
Unable to mount iPhone. Location already mounted.
```

While this can be solved by just re-plugging the USB cable, the alert window stays open and I cannot close it.

Sometimes I try to move it away to the side, and then after around 2-3 hours, the whole computer gets stuck and stops responding (I can move the mouse pointer, that’s it...) and I have to force restart the computer. I have noticed this only happens after I get the error message.

Image of the error: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQWMS.png

**Edit:** I tried the accepted answer at [iPhone mount errors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69663/iphone-mount-errors) but it didn’t work.

Answer (score 0):

I get it all the time. The trick is to get the PID of the opened windows (usually all the windows opened in this problem have the same PID). What you need is the following

```
wmctrl -l -p
```

This gives you the list of all opened windows with their PID and names! For example in my case it showed:

```
0x05000003  0 19086  Earthshake
0x05000008  0 19086  Earthshake mostafa's iPhone
0x05000012  0 19086  Earthshake
```

The 3rd column is the PID to kill! So, simply use the `kill` command. For example:

```
kill -9 19086
```