# nvidia-current as default graphic driver

Tags: 11.10, nvidia, graphics

I'm just recently used Ubuntu 11.10 for a change.
I've install it on a Dual-boot with Windows 7 - but eventually going to remove Windows.
I'm using a Asus K42Jc having an NVidia GeForce 310M chip. After installing ubuntu and following some steps on how to install nvidia on my laptop using the codes below, I can't still get my NVidia driver display on the System Info as the Graphics Driver.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

I wanted to have this setting for me to install Blender, Warcraft III, etc.
How can I resolve the matter?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your laptop switches between graphics cards when using Windows?

Comment: Yes. By default on Windows 7 64bit, it uses the Intel HD Graphics but when I always run heavy graphic utilization programs on NVidia via "Run on graphics processor" option.

Comment: Then you have 2 options: 1)Use bumblebee to switch between the Intel and the nvidia cards 2)use only the intel card for everything, that's why the driver won't pick your card

Comment: Will try your suggestion. Kindly post it as an answer... Sorry for the late reply.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change some settings on Nvidia cards type following in terminal ( [What is a terminal and how do I open and use it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38162/what-is-the-terminal) )

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-settings
```

This will install an app for making some changes to Nvidia settings. You can find it in unity by typing `nvidia setting`

Answer (score 0):

Disable optimus technolgy from bios. Bumblebee still is experimental but you can try it.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Can you supply a link for me to switch form Optimus to Bumblebee?

Comment: @Dr.Java See http://askubuntu.com/a/36936/6969