# Where can I find the command line?

Tags: unity, command-line, unity-dash

A basic question: Where do I find the command line?

There is a lot of information about commands and using the command line, but I'm an absolutely new Ubuntu user: I can't find find the command line.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the terminal?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/38162/what-is-the-terminal)

Answer (score 19):

You can open a terminal in Unity (the default [desktop enviroment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment) when you install Ubuntu 11.10) by pressing **Ctrl** + **Alt** + **T** or by:
Open the dash by pressing the top button in the launcher. You will see a screen similar to this:

[image: the unity dash]

In the search box, type in "terminal". Click the icon for terminal, or, if it is the first result, which I am assuming it is, press the enter key on your keyboard. Terminal will open. You can close it like any other program by pressing the red X in the upper right hand corner of the window. Hope that helps!

Comment: @bri Your'e Welcome! Could you please either my or enzotib's answer as answer? You can do this by clicking the checkmark underneath the up and down vote buttons. The checkmark will turn green when clicked.

Answer (score 15):

The key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>t</kbd> should start a terminal emulator, that is substantially what you call *command line*.

Alternatively, from the Dash search for `terminal` and launch it.

Comment: [This](http://vic.gedris.org/Manual-ShellIntro/1.2/ShellIntro.pdf) could be really helpful for learning Linux Commands from very basics.

Comment: `Ctrl-Alt-t` only works in Unity, but I imagine @bri *is* using that.

Answer (score 0):

One more alternative to launch the terminal in Ubuntu is to press  **CTRL + ALT**  and then type gnome-terminal in the pop up text box.