# How do I find and use the gnome terminal?

Tags: command-line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87363/where-can-i-find-the-command-line)
>   [How do I install the Cinnamon Desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94201/how-do-i-install-the-cinnamon-desktop)

I'm a very new user to Linux. I ditched Windows entirely and installed the first Ubuntu I found online (which turned out to be natty). However, I've used Windows my whole life and I don't understand much computer code. I keep hearing about a "terminal" but I can't figure out how to run it.

Can someone help me understand a little bit more how to get the terminal up and enter code into it?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! There anre many ways to open it, Ctrl Alt T being the fastest. If you just need to run a single command, you can press alt + F2 and run it that way.

Answer (score 5):

There is also the keyboard shortcut:
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Comment: I always change that to a one key combination. Just press it and TERMINAL! It's because I use it like 20 times a day.

Answer (score 2):

To access the Gnome Terminal you can press the Dash button which is the "Super" button or the button with the Windows Logo on it. Then type `terminal`, similar to the image below:

[image]

Also as a shortcut you can press <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> and the terminal window will also appear.

Answer (score 1):

Open the Dash (like the Start in Windows) or simply hit the <kbd>Super</kbd> key, <kbd>Windows</kbd> key on the keyboard and type:

```
Terminal
```

... and the terminal application will be displayed. Click on it and that's it.

That's the short version of how to open the terminal. There's a lot more to understand Linux then being able to open the terminal and type in commands.

Comment: And when it's running right-click on the icon on the launcher and pin it to the launcher, so it's more convenient for you next time.

Comment: Or you can drag the icon from the dash to the launcher.