# Installing XAMPP for all user

Tags: 11.04, lamp, xampp

Is there anyway to install XAMPP for all the user on Ubuntu 11.04 ?  It would be great and I hope there are some ways. Because it's disgusting to log off every time to run XAMPP.

I'm new to Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what your exact circumstances are but XAMPP is designed for one-person-development. It's a quick easy way to test sites locally. If you want a system wide server that all users can use, perhaps it's time to stop using it for something it wasn't designed, and is time to use a traditional LAMP stack instead.

```
sudo apt-get install lamp-server^
```

<sup>**Note:** The `^` on the end isn't a typo - it's how we denote tasks.</sup>

That should give you a very traditional LAMP setup which you can then customise as much as you like. For service configuration, I personally like the [SliceHost articles](http://articles.slicehost.com/ubuntu-10) (even though I'm not a customer there) as they cover most of the basics about getting Apache, PHP and MySQL playing happily and in a nice sane way.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing something wrong if you need to logout each time to run a simple LAMPP server. It sounds like you've downloaded a bundle from a website, but in Ubuntu you usually use the package manager to install software.

To installa Apache, PHP, MySQL and phpMyAdmin install the packages `apache2 libapache2-mod-php5 mysql-server phpmyadmin`. This can be done by running the next command in a [terminal](https://askubuntu.com/q/38162/6969)

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 libapache2-mod-php5 mysql-server phpmyadmin
```

Have a look at [How to avoid using sudo when working in /var/www?](https://askubuntu.com/q/46331/6969) if you want to know some ways to tweak the filesystem permissions. If multiple users need access / edit to the same files, I suggest to setup a SSH or FTP server.

Setting a SSH server up is as easy as installing the `openssh-server` package. Create a new account on the machine, set a password for it and grant it access to the files in `/var/www`. For using SSHFS, see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSHFS

Answer (score 0):

You can easily install xampp with the shell script here is the shell script that will automatically download xampp, install it in prcise location and arrange the htdocs permission. 
Download and install shell script: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/17475393/xampp.sh

For more information http://freshtutorial.com/xampp-linux/ Hope it helps you

Thanks