# How do I use acpi_call?

Tags: acpi

How am I supposed to run/install [acpi_call](https://github.com/peberlein/acpi_call)? I've found a similar solution on [the linux hybrid graphics blog](http://linux-hybrid-graphics.blogspot.com/2010/07/using-acpicall-module-to-switch-onoff.html), but still couldn't manage to run it.

Comment: The instructions you've followed seem to be correct. Which step did you get stuck on?

Comment: When I run test_off.sh it gives me:
`Trying \_SB.PCI0.P0P1.VGA._OFF: failed
Trying \_SB.PCI0.P0P2.VGA._OFF: failed
.....`
and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not know how to use that kernel module, I suggest you to stay away from it. In the past it has been used for disabling discrete video cards directly, but that does not make the kernel aware of the state change. The `test_off.sh` file should **not** be used as it's just wildly guessing some calls which may have negative effects on the hardware and software (e.g. crazy fans, lockups).

If you want to disable NVIDIA cads, have a look at [Bumblebee](http://bumblebee-project.org) which comes with [bbswitch](http://bumblebee-project.org/bbswitch), a module for toggling the power of nvidia cards on Optimus laptops. More information about Optimus laptops can be found on [Is a NVIDIA GeForce with Optimus Technology supported by Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/36930/6969)

The bumblebee/stable PPA provides the `acpi-call-tools` package. After [installing the PPA](https://askubuntu.com/q/4983/6969) you can [open a terminal](https://askubuntu.com/q/38162/6969), load the acpi_call module and perform an ACPI call by writing to the file. This requires root privileges.

Load the acpi_call module and define a convenience function for making an ACPI call:

```
$ sudo modprobe acpi_call
$ c(){ echo "$1" | sudo tee /proc/acpi/call >/dev/null && sudo cat /proc/acpi/call;echo;}
```

An example: execute the ACPI method `\_SB_.PCI0.GFX0._DOD` and retrieve the result of it:

```
$ c '\_SB_.PCI0.GFX0._DOD'
[0x80010100, 0x80010300, 0x80010410]
```

Comment: I think acpi-call-tools has been renamed to acpi-call-dkms in newer versions of ubuntu

Comment: @bryanph Seems correct, Ubuntu imported the acpi-call-dkms package via Debian and it appears in at least Ubuntu 15.10 Wily.

Answer (score 0):

Just use acpi_call_GUI and do it via graphic interface!

1. Ensure that you have installed java and git, if not install these packages:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre
   sudo apt-get install git
   ```
2. After that open a terminal and type the following commands:

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/marcoDallas/acpi_call_GUI.git
   cd acpi_call_GUI    
   sudo chmod +x install.sh    
   sudo ./install.sh
   ```
3. Execute it, type in terminal:

   ```
   sudo java -jar $HOME/acpi_call_GUI.jar
   ```
4. Use in order: install, deactivate and automates options,

Here's a step by step video tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h33bvoR14x8!

Here you can find the website and sources: https://github.com/marcoDallas/acpi_call_GUI

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: This doesn't explain how to use `acpi_call`. Also, none of this stuff is needed; simply `apt install acpi-call-dkms` can install `acpi_call`.

Answer (score 0):

I checked out a new call for

Aspire 5810T
V1.35

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:2a42] (rev 07) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV710/M92 [Mobility Radeon HD 4330/4350/4550] [1002:9552] (rev ff) (prog-if ff)
```

which is not documented anywhere but works great for me to switch of my ATI card:

```
\_SB_.PCI0.OVGA.SGOF
```

@MarcoDallas: thank you for your great work.