# Minecraft becomes blank after loading

Tags: 11.10, minecraft

I have Minecraft installed but whenever I open it, it shows the login screen, so I login, and then when I click login, the window turns black. When I tried to play in in browser, the same thing happened except the window turned whit. Please help guys! I feel like I've tried EVERYTHING! Thanks! =)

Oh and if you want a better look at the problem, I've created this video that is a recording of my desktop and shows what happens when I try to run Minecraft.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8CMsnwoUbEI

Answer (score 1):

Remove all your Java packages and start over.

1. Install `openjdk-6-jre`
2. Remove the hidden folder `~/.minecraft` (folder `.minecraft`, located in your Home folder)
3. Download the `minecraft.jar` from http://www.minecraft.net/download
4. Create `~/.local/share/applications/minecraft.desktop` containing (assuming that you have downloaded the file in `~/Downloads`):

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
   [Desktop Entry]
   Version=1.0
   Name=Minecraft
   Comment=Start Minecraft
   Exec=/usr/bin/java -cp ~/Downloads/minecraft.jar net.minecraft.LauncherFrame
   Terminal=false
   Type=Application
   Icon=minecraft.png
   Categories=Games;
   StartupNotify=false
   ```
5. Find a nice icon on the Internet for Minecraft and save it as `~/.local/share/icons/minecraft.png`
6. To start Minecraft, run desktop file that you've created. You can copy it to your desktop as well.

Comment: The file didn't open, I ran through your directions three times and I think I did everything right.

Comment: Can you [open a terminal](http://askubuntu.com/q/38162/6969) and run the command `/usr/bin/java -cp ~/Downloads/minecraft.jar net.minecraft.LauncherFrame` ? Please add the output of it to your question. What fails?

Comment: Yes I can run it. But the same thing happens, the window turns black.

Comment: Is there any output from the terminal command?  What does the command `update-alternatives --display java` output for you?

Comment: This is what happens when it shows the login screen.


(java:2502): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(java:2502): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(java:2502): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(java:2502): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

Comment: And this is what happens when i login and the windows turns black


27 achievements
174 recipes
Setting user: jimmiekosmo, 5779368988720023508
Exception in thread "Minecraft main thread" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/jimmiekosmo/.minecraft/bin/natives/liblwjgl.so: libjawt.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1928)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1825)
 at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:792)
 at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1059)
 at org.lwjgl.Sys$1.run(Sys.java:69)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

Comment: at org.lwjgl.Sys.doLoadLibrary(Sys.java:65)
 at org.lwjgl.Sys.loadLibrary(Sys.java:81)
 at org.lwjgl.Sys.<clinit>(Sys.java:98)
 at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:132)
 at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.a(SourceFile:180)
 at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run(SourceFile:648)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)



(Sry they are chopped up)

Comment: Please add those details to your question or http://paste.ubuntu.com/ it. Are you running a 64-bit system or not?

Comment: it is a 32 bit system

Answer (score 0):

Installing the proprietary Drivers might help.

Go to the dash, search for Jockey, and install the Driver for your Graphics Card .