# ath9k driver (re)installation

Tags: drivers, ubuntu-netbook

I only installed Ubuntu a couple of weeks ago but my friend showed me how to use aircrack.Anyways, he said that i needed to install a special driver for it and while i was trying to install it the instruction told me to uninstal the previous driver but the installation of the new driver didnt work, so now im stuck with no wireless drivers on my netbook.But, when i boot into windows it works fine,any tips?
Btw,i'm using an ar2427 wireless adapter on an asus eee pc 1001pq,please reply.

Comment: maybe you could try the upstream kernel... it seems like it solve the issue.
Link: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1046800

Answer (score 1):

Here are the step-by-step instructions:

1. Download a stable driver from [this link](http://www.orbit-lab.org/kernel/compat-wireless-3-stable/v3.1/compat-wireless-3.1.1-1.tar.bz2).
2. Copy the downloaded file in your Home directory.
3. Open a terminal and run the following commands:

   `tar xf compat-wireless-3.1.1-1.tar.bz2`

   `cd compat-wireless-3.1.1-1`

   `./scripts/driver-select ath9k`

   `make`

   `sudo make install`

   `sudo make unload`
4. Restart your computer.

Done!

Answer (score 0):

What instructions have you followed...? If your friend has removed a kernel module in /lib/modules/.../kernel/drivers/...., a reinstallation of the kernel package as described below suffices.

The wireless drivers are contained in the kernel package, so reinstalling the linux-image-...-generic package (where ... is the kernel version) should be enough. The [terminal command](https://askubuntu.com/q/38162/6969) for reinstalling the current loaded kernel is:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-$(uname -r)
```