# Nvidia driver cannot be installed with jockey for old hardware

Tags: 12.04, nvidia

I have a GeForce FX/5-series card and I cannot install the driver using the Additional Drivers (jokey) tool.

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 and installed all nvidia drivers, but my drivers are not activated, when I open Nvidia settings manager I get the following message:

> You do not appear to be using the NVIDIA X driver. Please edit your X configuration file (just run `nvidia-xconfig` as root), and restart the X server.

Can you help me with this?

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/990539

I made a bug report, anyone else with this problem should do the same so the developers will fix it more quickly

Comment: They should not "do the same" as it will lead to duplicates, but they should mark it as affecting them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The driver present in the Additional Drivers tool does not support your GeForce FX/5-series card.

According to the bug report you opened you need to remove the drivers currently installed in your system and install the `nvidia-173` package which should support GeForce FX/5-series cards out of the box.

For that first remove all Nvidia drivers from your system with the following commands

```
sudo apt-get remove nvidia-current nvidia-current-updates nvidia-settings nvidia-settings-updates
```

This will remove all installed Nvidia drivers from your system. When that is done you need to install the `nvidia-173`, do it by [opening a terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38162/what-is-the-terminal) and typing

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-173
```

After the driver is installed in your system create a new `xorg.conf` file with the command `sudo nvidia-xconfig` and reboot. Your system should be working and using the latest driver available for your card.

Comment: is this tested by those who have similar card as I have?

Comment: All old hardware that needs that driver will need to follow the instructions on the bug report you opened, they should be using this version of the driver, not the one suggested by jokey.

Comment: Trying to install nvidia-173 creates the issue that it requires `xorg-video-abi-10 but it is not installable`.  Apparently `xorg-video-abi-10` is either not yet created or has been retired.  --update: it seems that `xorg-video-abi-11` is already installed, which would explain a lot.

Comment: @Mechko you can also install the 173 legacy driver directly from the nvidia website.