# I'm running in low graphics mode on ubuntu 12.04, I have and nvidia fx 5500

Tags: 12.04, nvidia

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to fix “The system is running in low-graphics mode” error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error)

So, I'm running ubuntu along xp and I have an Nvidia geforce fx 5500 graphic card, in the normal boot it does not work I see a bad image screen, but if I open in recovery mode it works,but in low graphics mode. How can I make it work properly, it want let me install the latest nvidia drivers for my card, can someone help me?

Comment: sudo jockey-text xorg:nvidia_current <- run that in low mode and reboot.

Comment: it asks me for my sudo password, what is that?

Comment: If you installed this on your computer it should be the password you use to login.

Comment: u were right for the password thanks, now I'm trying

Comment: :( nothing changed, in the terminal it says: additional drivers then searching for available drivers...                           that's all I did reboot but nothing new, perhaps I have download and install this drivers from from the nvidia site?

Comment: Any other ideas fellows?

Comment: try to follow instructions on this link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/126905/nvidia-driver-cannot-be-installed-with-jockey-for-old-hardware/161242#161242