# Why don't 12.04 Nvidia drivers work on my GeForce 6150 LE?

Tags: nvidia, hardware, proprietary

I got a slimline s7600n and of course i put ubuntu 12.04 on it. Im using recommended proprietary drivers and they are just not working to well. My monitor is 1366x768 but it will only do 1360x768 and minecraft barely runs at all. Besides that everything is fine. But i gota play minecraft! help! lol Thanks. :)

Other specs is 
cpu amd athlon 64 dual core 2ghz
ram 1 gig
vid is 256mb 64bit
Not sure what other info yall need.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nvidia driver cannot be installed with jockey for old hardware](http://askubuntu.com/questions/126905/nvidia-driver-cannot-be-installed-with-jockey-for-old-hardware)

Answer (score 1):

The GeForce 6150 LE is *not supported* by the additional Nvidia drivers in 12.04. You need to install an older version of the drivers.

Please see the answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/126905/58612) for how to remove the current drivers and install the older ones.

Comment: That made things worse. :(

Comment: Sorry, uninstall that, and just make do with the open source `noveau` driver instead. Consider upgrading to something with a newer graphics [(yours is 8 years old)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeForce_6_Series), and this time, try to make sure it's isn't "nvidia inside" ;)