# How do I install drivers for Nvidia GeForce FX 5200 in 12.04?

Tags: drivers, video

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install extra drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-extra-drivers)
>   [Nvidia driver cannot be installed with jockey for old hardware](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126905/nvidia-driver-cannot-be-installed-with-jockey-for-old-hardware)

First let me state that I'm the newest of newbies and really don't know what I'm doing yet.
  The machine that I installed Ubuntu on is my old Win XP machine that already had the FX5200EP installed in it.  I'm trying to learn this flavor of Linux.  After installing Ubuntu and applying the updates I have 2 screens with exactly the same thing on them including the mouse pointer.  I can't find how to make it into a dual monitor configuration.  I searching the web I find what I believe to be the correct driver but have no idea of how to download it or install it. Any advice and assistance would be GREATLY appreciated.  HELP

Answer (score 1):

The FX5200EP is a graphics card with Nvidia's GeForce FX 5200 chip.

The current "Additional Drivers" for Nvidia do not support the relatively old FX/5 series. Please see the below answer for complete instructions on how to install a compatible additional driver:

> [Nvidia driver cannot be installed with jockey for old hardware](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126905/nvidia-driver-cannot-be-installed-with-jockey-for-old-hardware)