# Cannot install drivers for GeForce 5600

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I'm trying to get ubuntu on a machine w/ an old video card (nVidia GeForce 5600).  I'm able to get to the desktop w/ a fresh install of 14.04 but its really laggy.  I've tried the default nvidia legacy driver as well as 173 as explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126905/nvidia-driver-cannot-be-installed-with-jockey-for-old-hardware).  Legacy drivers boot to a black screen, 173 black screens after unity's login.  I've also tried installing the latest nvidia drivers but they say this card is so old that it will just use the same legacy drivers that are preloaded.  I tried installing 12.04 but that boots to a black screen also.  The 320gb wd hdd has been scanned for bad sectors and the dvd drive and boot dvd have been replaced.  Its a sempron 3200 w/ 1gb ram.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Install the accelerated driver:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
```

Comment: That is the preloaded driver that runs very slowly.  I tried anyway and it said it already exists and its the newest version.