# Can not run Okular due to "Unable to find Okular component error"

Tags: okular

I've installed ubuntu 12.04 and installed okular but with normal user i can't run okular and give me an error that "Unable to find the Okular component." but with root user i can run it without any errors.
what should i do?

I've tried to `purge` and `install` okular itself, but this has not worked.

Comment: How did you install Okular? With Ubuntu Software Center or `sudo apt-get install` or ...?

Comment: Same issue as https://askubuntu.com/q/1070081/446253 which pinpoints problems with q5, like https://askubuntu.com/q/1114346/446253. These refer to release **18.04**, so it's a recurring glitch

Answer (score 1):

You should never run GUI programs as root unless *explicitly* noted. Changes are that files in your home directory now have wrong ownership. Find those files and restore the ownership:

1. [Open a terminal](https://askubuntu.com/q/38162/6969)
2. (optional, but recommended for verifying) Find all files that are not owned by you:

   sudo find ~ ! -user $(id -u) -ls
3. Find all files and restore the ownership to yours:

   sudo find ~ ! -user $(id -u) -exec chown $(id -u) {} \; -ls

If unsure, you can leave a comment here with a link to http://paste.ubuntu.com/ containing the output of step 2.