# Okular no longer working in terminal after Kubuntu 18 upgrading

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu, shared-library, okular

I have recently upgraded from Kubuntu 16 to 18. 
When I try to run okular in a terminal (konsole) as a user (as I have been successfully doing before, in vs 16), in vs 18 it fails, giving a message error: "Unable to find the okular component: The shared library was not found".
I can run okular from the Application Menu, and also from terminal provided I run it with sudo, but not when I try as a user. I wonder what has changed in the upgrading and how to fix the problem.
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. By Kubuntu 18 I gather you mean 18.04 LTS (ie. 2018.April release).  Normally an error message tells you the shared library it was looking for that it couldn't find, so please re-run it and copy & whole message(s) & paste into your question so we can see what actually is missing, to help you rectify your issue. There are a number of libraries used by okular (https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/okular)

Comment: @guiverc The puzzling thing is that `okular` runs from the "Application Menu" but apparently not from the terminal unless the user uses `sudo`!!! And `okular` works for me whether I access it from the terminal or from the Application Menu or by double-clicking on a pdf file in Dolphin (the file manager). The mysteries of upgrading?

Comment: You may also have a snap of `okular` installed, and it's being run from the menu, but not from terminal (due to order of listed directories maybe - use `snap list` to view what snaps you have installed). With snaps you can multiple versions of programs installed.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/questions/133274/can-not-run-okular-due-to-unable-to-find-okular-component-error since it works with sudo.

Comment: If you get any output from running `find . -user root -ls` I suggest you refer to the link I posted above.

Comment: Yes, by Kubuntu 18 I mean 18.04 LTS (just for short). I have tried with `okular`and `/usr/bin/okular`. In both cases, the only message that I got is that appearing in a pop-up window as quoted in my query. No message appeared in the terminal.  It is unlikely that some library is lacking as I can run okular in terminal as root. I have run `snap list` as suggested by @guiverc obtaining "No snaps are installed yet".  I have followed the instructions in the link provided by @DKBose so that running in my user `find . -user root -ls` now gives no output. The problem remains the same.

Comment: Double clicking on a pdf file in Dolphin also works.

Comment: When I run `okular file.pdf` (i.e. passing the name of an existing pdf file as argument), apart from the message in the pop-up window, I get this message in the terminal: "org.kde.kwindowsystem: Could not find any platform plugin"

Comment: If you get no issues when run as root, then you may have changed a setting whilst using 'root' & have thus forced change-of-permissions meaning you have issues when no longer running as root (*my thinking is instead of writing the config/other change, it read & re-wrote the file making owner=root as side effect of you using root at the time*)  I don't have the program (or KDE) loaded on this box so I don't know where to look, but I'd look for a config file owned by root possibly in ~/.local or ~/.config (or subdirectories in each *- look for okular files; `chown` to yourself if owned by root*)

Comment: Same problem in **Ubuntu 18.04**. Take note that the program does not crash; if I do `pgrep okular` I get a pid. And, as mentioned elsewhere, I can launch the program regularly from the application menu: the problem only occurs in the shell.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is not the solution you are asking for, but I fixed this on my machine by removing the snap version of Okular and installing the apt version instead.

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer to the mystery. It was in my `.bashrc` file which contained a line:
`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/Qt/5.10.1/gcc_64/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` which caused this and other similarly odd problems with other applications (`kile`for instance). This appeared after upgrading, as that line was harmless before. I must finally mention that the quoted library directory exists in my installation (i.e. the problem is not caused because the directory is lacking).

Comment: How did you then fix the issue? For example, on removing that line or giving another location? I gather that that path element had a purpose to provide Qt 5.10.1 to some other applications