# Okular does not want to open pdf's saved through Zotero

Tags: pdf, okular, zotero

I am very new to Linux / Ubuntu and have been playing around with it for the past week.
I have come across a problem I can't seem to fix. 
If I want to open a PDF with Okular, which has been stored / filed through Zotero, I get the following message:

```
Could not open file:///home/ingrid/snap/zotero-snap/common/Zotero/storage/GI4FVK9I/Vranken - 2020 - Rooted Hauntology Lab Attempts at vegetal curatio.pdf
```

The only program that can open the files seems to be pdf viewer, but this does not have the functionality I need. 
Thank you for helping me out!!

Comment: Ah my apologies! I found the solution by delving deeper into this amazing archive. The second suggestion of this: https://askubuntu.com/a/1114357/1063723
worked for me. Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Suddenly Okular will not open any more](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1114346/suddenly-okular-will-not-open-any-more)