# Remove Windows 8 boot

Tags: system-installation

Installed Ubuntu over a Windows 8 trial. After installation, Windows 8 still tries to boot.  Wiped disk clean with Acronis and reinstall Ubuntu. Windows 8 still tries to start, but goes to blank screen.  Ubuntu never tries to boot. Naturally live mode works fine. What do you think of wiping disk again, install Windows 7 and try using GRUB approach or do you know how to remove Windows from the cleaned disk?

Comment: Boot from the LiveCD and run `sudo fdisk -l`, edit your question and add the output of that command to it.

Comment: This might be an UEFI issue. When selecting the boot device to start from the live CD (or USB drive), are you able to choose between (U)EFI and non-EFI?

Comment: @soulsource : I'm pretty sure for windows 8 it is a requirement to boot from UEFI.

Comment: @Schweinsteiger : I know about Windows. Ubuntu on the other hand can be booted either by UEFI or by Bios. Only if you boot the installation CD/USB-Drive with UEFI it installs an UEFI bootloader and only then it will be possible to boot the installed system from UEFI without Bios compatibility. Of course there are some other ways to install an UEFI bootloader after installing Ubuntu.

Comment: @soulsource : Exactly.
Parley : In the Bios option you need to choose "UEFI:USB" . If you boot ubuntu in UEFI,then the bootloader will be properly installed.

Answer (score 1):

Theres two options to boot an Operating System from..

1. MBR (Master Boot Record) Boot sector at very beginning of Disk drive
2. Boot Sector of each partition

some OS's like MS.Windows affects MBR and you need to place grub boot loader at MBR.
for this purpose:

**Step 1:**  Boot up your system with any grub installed emergency disk.
(like : *Gparted Emergency, HBCD, Bootable Grub, or Puppy linux*)

**Step 2:**  Run gparted program or this command: ***df*** and determine what is your drive name (result is like: **/dev/sda**) without any number at end of **/sda**

**Step 3:**  if grub is preinstalled then run these commands in shell (terminal):

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
sudo grub-setup /dev/sda
```

and if its not installed,do this command:

```
sudo apt-get install grub
```

anyway you need to edit **/boot/grub/grub.cfg** to enable resume function (Hybernate)

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need to install Windows 7 to edit your GRUB. You could also run a live copy of Ubuntu on a flash drive and then edit your GRUB file following this wiki guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2

Alternatively, if the GRUB menu doesn't open automatically upon startup, try holding down the SHIFT key before Windows 8 boots. That usually signals it to open, if it's installed properly.

Answer (score 0):

Do you see GRUB menu or not? May be you have just installed GRUB loader in wrong partition (not the one you are booting from). You can select partition for GRUB loader during setup while selecting partition to setup Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install GRUB on your hard disk. You can do this by using the Ubuntu Live CD.

1. Boot to the Live CD. When you get the Ubuntu Live Desktop, Open terminal ( [What is a terminal and how do I open and use it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38162/what-is-the-terminal) ) and type the following:

   ```
   sudo grub
   ```

   This will get you a **grub>** prompt (i.e. the grub shell).
2. At grub>. enter these commands

   ```
   find /boot/grub/stage1
   ```

   This will return a location. If you have more than one, select the installation that you want to provide the grub files.
3. **This is important**: what was returned for the find command use it in the next line for the "?" -

   ```
   root (hd?,?)
   ```

   Again use the value from the find command i.e. if find returned `(hd0,1)` then you would enter `root (hd0,1)`
4. Next enter the command to install grub to the mbr

   ```
   setup (hd0)
   ```
5. Finally exit the grub shell

   ```
   quit
   ```

Now you are done. Reboot the machine.

---

Another option is to run this command:

```
grub-install /dev/hda
```