# A Disk Read Error Occured. Press CTRL+ALT+DEL to restart

Tags: grub2

I'm new to linux world. Just  downloaded ubuntu and installed it alongside with windows 7  . In grub when I choose ubuntu, it opens with no problem, but when I try to open windows 7, this message appears:

```
A Disk Read Error Occured. Press CTRL+ALT+DEL to restart.
```

I googled for that  problem which  directed me to download a boot repair tool, 
when I choose : `advanced options / retore MBR --> apply`, then restart computer , It boot to win 7 without loading the grub menu.

then I opened the live ubuntu from a  USB,  launched the "boot repair" again, choose : recommended repair , then restart, It  returns to the first  problem , grub menu appear, from which I can choose only ubuntu , but win 7 show this msg again :

```
A Disk Read Error Occured. Press CTRL+ALT+DEL to restart.
```

I repeated more and more with the same results ...

What should I do?

I created a boot info summary using the "boot repair tool" if this can help , it's in [this URL](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1356081/).

Comment: follow [this answer][1] you would be lucky!


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/a/217134/82136

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. It appears that either grub2, or the way Ubuntu implemented grub2, does not detect Windows partitions properly. I had a co-worker help me with this. First get grub working. Then I added the code below in `/etc/grub.d/08_custom`. Then `update-grub`. This puts Windows above Ubuntu so it will boot by default.

If you wish to boot Ubuntu by default, modify `40_custom` instead. This will create a new entry for Windows along with the useless entry that was originally found. Select the custom entry to boot Windows. My new `grub.cfg` is at http://paste.ubuntu.com/1368590/.

Here is the contents of my `08_custom`:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec tail -n +3 $0
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
    menuentry 'Windows 7 (customized entry)' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntfs
    set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
    chainloader +1
}
```