# .run file is not working. I double click and get: could not display, file is of unknown type

Tags: nvidia, display

So, the only thing I can think of is that Ubuntu did not correctly install some software as it doesn't recognize .run files. I checked "allow to run as executable file", but nothing.

Answer (score 0):

> `.run` files are usually scripts. You can open them with text editor to see what is inside. In most cases, double clicking them should either run, or prompt asking you whether to run.

If the GUI does not provide an option to run them,

- Open a [terminal](https://askubuntu.com/q/38162/45659) ( Shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> )
- Change directory. Type `cd /path/to/file` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- `ls -l <file-name>.run` and see the output.

  - If you dont see a 'x' in the first collumn, Type `chmod +x <file-name>.run` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
  - If you see something like `-rwxrwxr-x` , skip to next step.
     <sub>This is to check if the file is executable, and make it if it is not.</sub>
- Type `./<file-name>.run` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: when I use the ls -l <file-name>.run it shows verbatim: -rwxrwxrwx 1 zerik zerik 58529488

I follow using chmod +x, and it still says "cannot execute binary file

Comment: The file has proper permissions set. The problem must be elsewhere. We need more information on what file this is, to help you.

Comment: I was trying to run my install.bin file by mouse click on the file. It has execution permission but still runs only from terminal command. If i remove .bin extension, it works fine. Any Idea ?