# boot problem after updating to 14.04

Tags: boot, 14.04

I've installed 14.04 (from 11.10), it worked first, than I tried to install the 64-bit-version, which doesn't seem to be able to boot because of my old BIOS, which does not allow "efi" boot.
Now I reinstalled 14.04 32 bit, but still get a grub rescue prompt when trying to boot. Running boot-repair from live ubuntu didn't help.
So here's the report boot-repair made:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/7410732

Hope someone can help me ...

Comment: possible dupe http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows

Comment: and http://askubuntu.com/questions/386467/error-file-grub-i386-pc-normal-mod-not-found-in-ubuntu-13-10

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to install the 64-bit-version, which doesn't seem to be able
>   to boot because of my old BIOS, which does not allow "efi" boot

The 14.04 image will boot without EFI. You could also try the ["amd64+mac" image](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/14.04/release/ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64+mac.iso) which is BIOS only (no EFI).

> Now I reinstalled 14.04 32 bit, but still get a grub rescue prompt
>   when trying to boot

Boot from a livecd and do:

```
mount /dev/sda5 /mnt
grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt /dev/sda
reboot
```

Comment: I did what bain advised and got the
error: file `/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found.
grub then entered rescue mode
What can I do now??

Comment: Was the grub-install successful or were there any warnings or errors? Do you have a separate /boot partition?

Comment: Does /dev/sda5 contain the /boot/grub/i386-pc directory? It is possible that grub is doing an efi install for some reason, in which case follow @cbaoth's answer in [error: file '/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found in ubuntu 13.10](http://askubuntu.com/questions/386467/error-file-grub-i386-pc-normal-mod-not-found-in-ubuntu-13-10), substituting /dev/sda1 for your /dev/sda5.

Comment: Thanks so far - but no success yet. - The i386-pc directory is found on the boot partition. However, this partition seems to be sort of a sub-partition. When executing gparted, it shows "/dev/sda1 (linux swap); /dev/sda2 (ntfs); /dev/sda3 (extended) and within this /dev/sda5 (ext4)". The latter is the one with the boot flag and contains the /boot/grub/i386-pc directory. - Maybe the fact of beeing a sub-partition disables the boot process to find the boot directory?

Comment: @user271850 grub should work with a logical partition. Have a look at my answer on [error: file '/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found](http://askubuntu.com/questions/266429/error-file-grub-i386-pc-normal-mod-not-found), it may help.

Comment: Got the problem fixed now - the cause was to simple to think of: During installation I had to change boot options in my BIOS to enable boot from USB device. After installing I made a mistake in resetting the BIOS, so the system tried to boot from my second HDD which could not work. Unplugging the 2nd HDD lead me to the solution!