# Ubuntu server error: file '/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found. grub rescue>

Tags: 14.04, boot, server, grub2

Hi i installed the latest Ubuntu server 14.04 and rebooted a few times perfectly and now when i last reboot it, i get the following error:

```
error: file '/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found.
grub rescue>
Entering rescue mode...
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

fixed it by setting to disable a certain boot method EFI located from my bios

link here

[error: file '/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found in ubuntu 13.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/386467/error-file-grub-i386-pc-normal-mod-not-found-in-ubuntu-13-10)