# grub error: /boot/grub2/i386-pc/normal.mod not found

Tags: grub2, 64-bit, 32-bit

When I use USB flash memory (Ubuntu 14.04 amd64) for booting my PC (win 7 x64), I get the following error:

```
error: file '/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found.
grub rescue>
```

But using this USB flash memory on my laptop (win 7 x64), grub loads correctly.

I read these questions but they didn't help:

[Ubuntu server error: file '/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found. grub rescue>](https://askubuntu.com/questions/549230/ubuntu-server-error-file-grub-i386-pc-normal-mod-not-found-grub-rescue)

[error: file '/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found in ubuntu 13.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/386467/error-file-grub-i386-pc-normal-mod-not-found-in-ubuntu-13-10)

[error: file '/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/266429/error-file-grub-i386-pc-normal-mod-not-found)

I removed the hard disc from PC, yet I get the above error, at boot time with USB.

My PC's BIOS settings has not two booting options; EFI or Legacy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by using a different method to make the bootable USB.

The best software for this is [unetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/).