# Unable to install ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, 16.04, system-installation, usb, 32-bit

I've tried to Install Ubuntu 16.04 many times and failed (whenever I attempt to install it again, I select the "Erase disk and Install Ubuntu" option). I have the boot USB loaded with the .iso file (made it with rufus, as shown in [this link](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)), I've made sure that its the 32bit installer ([this torrent](http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04.1/ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-i386.iso.torrent?_ga=1.153640955.211620493.1473212468)). 
Installation goes normally, up to the point where it asks me to reboot, after startup, the computer sends me the following error:

```
error:file'/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found
Entering rescue mode...
grub recue>
```

Yes, I have tried to launch terminal in the 'trial' ubuntu version from the usb, and install everything mannually, it didnt work (as told on [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/266429/error-file-grub-i386-pc-normal-mod-not-found), and [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/386467/error-file-grub-i386-pc-normal-mod-not-found-in-ubuntu-13-10)).

Quick computer info:

- Hard Drive: 500gb
- RAM: x2 4GB DDR3 1600MHz
- Processor: intel Core i3
- Computer Model: Dell Latitude E5410

This is a new Hard Drive, with nothing on it (except maybe the last attempt I made installing Ubuntu) and I've followed every step in the guides, I seriously have no idea what's going on. Thanks in advance

Comment: might try the solutions offered [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/266429/error-file-grub-i386-pc-normal-mod-not-found#286028) for that error