# Ubuntu VM fails to boot on Virtualbox - boot directory is empty

Tags: boot, dual-boot, virtualbox

I'm trying to boot up an Ubuntu VM, but I am getting an error that `/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod` cannot be found. When I check the directory in rescue mode, the boot folder is empty.

Also, I am trying to boot from a `.iso` file corresponding to the correct version of VirtualBox, but that doesn't seem to be having any impact

[image: screenshot of my settings is attached below]

Anyone able to help?

Much appreciated!
Ben

Comment: Your `Controller IDE` says `secondary master` should it not be `primary master` and usually when install finishes the `Controller IDE` should be empty..

Comment: I did make some changes on the storage settings to try to get it to work, but switching it to primary master and/or removing the optical disk so that it is empty still gives the same error as before

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error: file '/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found in ubuntu 13.10](http://askubuntu.com/questions/386467/error-file-grub-i386-pc-normal-mod-not-found-in-ubuntu-13-10)